# Is there a way to clear Python's IDLE window?

Tags: python, python-idle

I know there's a similar topic about the Python console, but I do not know if they are the same. I tried `system("clear")` and it didn't work here.

How do I clear Python's [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE) window?

Comment: it is not a duplicate, OP is asking about how to clear IDLE shell, not  console

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is because Python starts a new shell session and runs the command `clear` in there. It also explains why `cd` doesn't work in `system.os`.

Comment: Hold down `ctrl + j` for a while and then press enter, That will be the best way

Comment: @ytpillai, Ah, but that gives me the prompt at the bottom. A solution, no doubt, but still causes some convenience.

Comment: Not a solution, but for anyone else that was curious, the `EditorWindow` object that the IDLEX extension uses to clear the console seems to be accessible within IDLE using (at the prompt) `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals['self'].rpchandler.console`, though anything involving the `text` attribute locks up the console so it's not much help.

Comment: Re *"a similar topic about the Python console"*: That could be *[How can I clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-python-interpreter-console)*. Yes, they are different. [Ctrl + L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810537/how-to-clear-the-screen-in-python#comment27752829_4810537) does not work in IDLE.

Answer (score 112):

The "cls" and "clear" are commands which will clear a terminal (ie a DOS prompt, or terminal window).  From your screenshot, you are using the shell within IDLE, which won't be affected by such things.  Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to clear the screen in IDLE.  The best you could do is to scroll the screen down lots of lines, eg:

```
print ("\n" * 100)
```

Though you could put this in a function:

```
def cls(): print ("\n" * 100)
```

And then call it when needed as `cls()`

Comment: It does clear the screen but you still get the prompt ">>> "at the last line rather on top , which i guess make its less more inefficient ...still +1 for clear Screen

Comment: Python 3.4.2 - I had to encase "\n" and * 100 in parentheses, so: `print ("\n" * 100)`

Comment: This won't clear the screen, I can still scroll back up!

Comment: `ctrl + j` also works. Might be useful including that. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11993793/4871483

Comment: Note this is python tag. Non version specific. For all python 3.x users it is `print('\n'*100)`

Comment: ha ha ha def cls(): print "\n" * 100

Comment: It does not clear the screen it just prints a lot of newlines

Comment: Python shell says squeezed text 100 lines @Brian

Comment: Where does this function gets stored? and how can i change it?

Comment: doesn't work on windows python idle..

Answer (score 111):

`os.system('clear')` works on Linux. If you are running Windows try `os.system('CLS')` instead.

You need to import *os* first, like this:

```
import os
```

Comment: The os.system('CLS') works in Windows.   (Python 2.6).   The resulting screen is cleared, only showing a "0", which I assume is the return value for CLS, at the top.  The next line has the >>> prompt.

Comment: Well, it doesn't clear the python shell. But I can see the 0 print.

Comment: This does not work in the Windows Idle tkinter shell, although it probably works in the command line.

Comment: this makes an os call to cls in an external command prompt and doesn't interact w/ Idle

Comment: In addition to Nadia's solution I suggest adding the following lines to your (PYTHONSTARTUP)[http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP] file so you can clear the screen faster: `                                                                                                                                                                          
import os
def c():
    os.system('clear')
` Edit: no multiline code in comments.. but you understand my shortcut right?

Comment: idle is not a console window. Both clear and cls operate on console/terminal windows.

Comment: The question is 'clear screen IN IDLE' the above methods certainly do not work on my computer

Comment: @devouredelysium In a console, assign `os.system("clear")` to a variable to not see the 0.

Comment: Why is this upvoted? This will open a new command prompt, clear it, and close it

Comment: I'm using VS CODE on mac for teaching OOP purposes with a text-based menu system. This works on the TERMINAL WINDOW only, not the debug console. 
It suits my purposes for clearing before displaying a new menu. (Just clarifying why I find this answer  useful)

Comment: This worked for me on a windows terminal, to avoid the resulting 0 I just put it inside a funtion:
```python
def cls():
    os.system('cls')
```
and then just call `cls()` when I need to clear the screen

Comment: @devouredelysium try this: _ = os.system('clear')

Answer (score 68):

Most of the answers, here do clearing the DOS prompt screen, with clearing commands, which is not the question. Other answers here, were printing blank lines to show a clearing effect of the screen.

The simplest answer of this question is

> It is not possible to clear python IDLE shell without some external module integration. If you really want to get a blank pure fresh shell just close the previous shell and run it again

Comment: This is a good, direct, and practical answer to this question; close idle, leave the file open, run the file again and idle now has a fresh screen.

Comment: @Mike_K, it can be be useful, but not ever. Right now I have a splitted screen (a book <|> idle). When I reexecute the Idle, the new screen comes in the default position/dimensions. So, it will get very boring.

Comment: So, they didn't implement the most simple thing. It didn't have to be a command, but a button in the view menu.

Answer (score 53):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> clears the screen on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Also on Red Hat/Fedora/CentOS

Comment: On Windows too, if you use IDLEx. Cheers! So happy to have finally gotten a simple solution!

Comment: Not working in Ubuntu 18.04. The less worse here is use `CTRL` + `J` multiple times.

Comment: @slinstj that closed it altogether on windows

Comment: Added to my today hack! Also work like a charm in MacOS!

Comment: Maybe your answer is key combination for `print ("\n" * 100)`

Answer (score 26):

An extension for clearing the shell can be found in [Issue6143](http://bugs.python.org/issue6143) as a "feature request". This extension is included with [IdleX](http://idlex.sourceforge.net).

Comment: This is a brilliant extension to Python Idle. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 21):

Use:

```
>>> import os

>>>def cls():
...    os.system("clear")
...
>>>cls()
```

That does it perfectly. A '0' isn't printed either.

Comment: Nice, simple, does what it says. Or after `import os` just type `os.system("clear")` although the function's handy if you often need to clear the screen.

Comment: os.system("clear") worked. This works for me, but i have to type "cls()"

Comment: When I tried this, the command line returned <function cls at 0x024D25D0> and the console didn't clear

Comment: Best answer so far

Comment: @ericgrosse you need to type cls(), not cls

Comment: A simple one liner `def cls(): import os; os.system('clear')`

Comment: dosn't work for windows python idle

Answer (score 13):

There does not appear to be a way to clear the IDLE 'shell' buffer.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue6143 has an extension to clear the shell, and is included with IdleX.

Answer (score 6):

The way to execute commands in Python 2.4+ is to use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module. You can use it in the same way that you use `os.system`.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("clear") # Linux and Mac
subprocess.call("cls", shell=True) # Windows
```

If you're executing this in the Python console, you'll need to do something to hide the return value (for either `os.system` or `subprocess.call`), like assigning it to a variable:

```
cls = subprocess.call("cls", shell=True)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.call("cls")
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 444, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 804, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] System cannot find the specified file

Comment: Hmm.. That's what I get for not using Windows and thus not being able to test it. Try subprocess.call("cls", shell=True)

Answer (score 6):

I like to use:

```
import os
clear = lambda : os.system('cls') # or clear for Linux

clear()
```

Comment: Looks like that answer has [already been provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1432505/2308683)

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for Mac OS X.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for Ubuntu.

It clears the last line in the interactive session.

Comment: I didn't know about this feature, thanks 
Always write what your command does.

Answer (score 5):

File -> New Window

**In the new window****

Run -> Python Shell

The problem with this method is that it will clear all the things you defined, such as variables.

Alternatively, you should just use command prompt.

open up command prompt

type "cd c:\python27"

type "python example.py" , you have to edit this using IDLE when it's not in interactive mode. If you're in python shell, file -> new window.

Note that the example.py needs to be in the same directory as C:\python27, or whatever directory you have python installed.

Then from here, you just press the UP arrow key on your keyboard. You just edit example.py, use CTRL + S, then go back to command prompt, press the UP arrow key, hit enter.

If the command prompt gets too crowded, just type "clr"

The "clr" command only works with command prompt, it will not work with IDLE.

Comment: Just Saying, but I believe that the question is asking 'How do you clear the screen IN IDLE FROM INSIDE THE PYTHON SCRIPT.

Comment: Starting new file and running Python shell in it appeared to be the only option available to me, nothing else worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It seems like there is no direct way for clearing the IDLE console.

One way I do it is use of exit() as the last command in my python script (.py). When I run the script, it always opens up a new console and prompt before exiting.

Upside : Console is launched fresh each time the script is executed.
Downside : Console is launched fresh each time the script is executed.

Answer (score 3):

As [mark.ribau said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432480/is-there-a-way-to-clear-pythons-idle-window/1435237#1435237), it seems that there is no way to clear the Text widget in IDLE. One should edit the `EditorWindow.py` module and add a method and a menu item in the EditorWindow class that does something like:

```
self.text.tag_remove("sel", "1.0", "end")
self.text.delete("1.0", "end")
```

and perhaps some more tag management of which I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 3):

None of these solutions worked for me on Windows 7 and within IDLE.  Wound up using PowerShell, running Python within it and exiting to call "cls" in PowerShell to clear the window.

CONS: Assumes Python is already in the PATH variable.  Also, this does clear your Python variables (though so does restarting the shell).

PROS: Retains any window customization you've made (color, font-size).

Comment: How did you do this: "Wound up using PowerShell, running Python within it and exiting to call "cls" in PowerShell to clear the window" ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems it is impossible to do it without any external library.

An alternative way if you are using windows and don't want to open and close the shell everytime you want to clear it is by using windows command prompt.

- Type `python` and hit enter to turn windows command prompt to python idle (make sure python is installed).
- Type `quit()` and hit enter to turn it back to windows command prompt.
- Type `cls` and hit enter to clear the command prompt/ windows shell.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it on windows is using the command prompt 'cmd' and access the Python directory. The command prompt could be found on the start menu → *Run* → *cmd*.

```
C:
cd C:\Python27
python.exe
```

Output:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
```

Session:

```
>>>import os
>>>os.system('cls')  #This will clear the screen and return the value 0
```

Comment: Just Saying, but I believe that the question is asking 'How do you clear the screen IN IDLE'. (Emphasis on `IN IDLE`)

Comment: This will ***NOT*** work, at least not on Linux. It prints some [process ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) (`32512` when I tried it in IDLE 3.8.10 on Ubuntu) and doesn't clear anything. I imagine it will be similar on Windows.

Comment: cont' - It may be an example of the many, many completely bogus answers on Stack Overflow (e.g., copy-paste search engine jobs without actually testing the result).

Answer (score 2):

You can make an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script.

To set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to a hotkey to clear the shell:

```
^r::SendInput print '\n' * 50 {Enter}
```

Just install AutoHotkey, put the above in a file called *idle_clear.ahk*, run the file, and your hotkey is active.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [Thonny IDE](http://thonny.org/) for Python. It's shell has "Clear Shell" option and you can also track variables created in a separate list. It's debugging is very good even comparing with modern IDEs. You can also write code in python file along with access to shell at the same place.

And its lightweight!

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
for num in range(1,100):
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Works, but you end up with an incredibly long scroll distance if you want to see something from earlier.

Comment: Try to reduce the range(1,10):

Comment: @Xenon   But if the idea is to clear the window, so the user shouldn't be able to be able to view something from earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Turtle can clear the screen.

```
#=====================================
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Clear the Screen")

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.color('red', 'yellow')
t.speed(0)

#=====================================

def star(x, y, length, angle):
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pendown()
    t.begin_fill()
    while True:
        t.forward(length)
        t.left(angle)
        if t.heading() == 0: #===============
            break
    t.end_fill()
#=====================================
#   (  x,    y,  length, angle)
star(-360,  0,    150,    45)
t.clear()
#=====================================
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for IDLE, not for the command prompt and was tested with Python 3.10.6.

If you press Ctrl+Z while the code is running (before it finishes), the previous output will be erased. If you wish to automate this, there's the [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) package.

```
pip install pynput
```

Here's a sample code (macros are unsafe, use it at your own risk):

```
# License: MIT-0
import time
import pynput

class _Eraser:
    keyboard = pynput.keyboard.Controller()
    ctrl = pynput.keyboard.Key.ctrl
    is_initialized = False

    @classmethod
    def erase(cls, n):
        if not cls.is_initialized:
            cls.is_initialized = True
            n += 1
        for _ in range(n):
            with cls.keyboard.pressed(cls.ctrl):
                cls.keyboard.press('z')
                cls.keyboard.release('z')
        time.sleep(0.1)

def erase(n=1):
    _Eraser.erase(n)

print('test1\n', end='')
print('test2\n', end='')
erase()  # Erase 'test2\n'
print('test3')
print('test4')
erase()  # Erase '\n'
print('test5')
print('test6')
erase(2)  # Erase '\n' and then 'test6'
print('test7')
```

The output is:

```
test1
test3
test4test5
test7
```

Answer (score -3):

This works for me in Windows:

`print chr(12)`

Comment: chr is not recognized in IDLE terminal

Comment: Thanks Joel. Worked for me too.

Comment: Works for me too in Windows, Spyder IDE, and seems to be the simplest code to achieve the desired result. {chr(12) is formfeed}

Answer (score -9):

There is no need to write your own function to do this! Python has a built in clear function.

Type the following in the command prompt:

```
shell.clear()
```

If using `IPython` for Windows, it's

```
cls()
```

Comment: Is there some kind of import required for doing this, because it didn't work for me. If there is an import involved, you should put it into your response. Also, the question is about clearing the prompt _IN IDLE_.

Comment: The OP [has left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 10 years ago"*

Comment: Probably another completely bogus answer on Stack Overflow.