# How to get to a new line in Python Shell?

Tags: python, python-idle

I want to write the following two lines on the console:

```
x = 3

print x**5
```

But when I type `x = 3`, I press enter, it then executes the assignment. How to get it to execute only after typing the second line?

Comment: @Wooble Because if I want to write a 100-words program, I have to type all of them in one line...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

End lines with `;\`:

```
>>> x=3;\
... print x**5
243
>>>
```

Comment: Blah, that's nasty (but legal).

Comment: Yeah it works, but two questions: 1.where did you learn this, in Python tutorial? 2.This is too unnatural, is there a way i can just type Enter to go to a new line, like in most IDEs?

Comment: @asunnysunday: You're working in an interactive interpreter. If you want to enter more than one statement before its executed, you'll need to use a file. In IDLE create a new file, then you can execute the file through IDLE. The window that's likely titled "Python Shell" is an interactive interpreter.

Comment: @asunnysunday 1. Right there in the manual: http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining . 2. No. Instead, use a regular (or IDLE's) editor, and execute the whole Python program.

Answer (score 37):

Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> key sequence instead of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to get a plain newline plus indentation without having IDLE start interpreting your code.

You can find other key sequences that make IDLE easier to use for this type of learning under the `Options->Configure` IDLE menu.

Comment: Does not seem to work with the original question though, if I type "x=3[C-j]print x**5" nothing is printed.

Comment: Seems you can also use Shitf+Enter too (tried in Mac terminal)

Comment: Note: some shells will require you to escape the Ctrl-J with a preceding Ctrl-V.

Comment: when adding new lines.. how do you eventually run the multiple lines? cmd/crl-c returns in a KeyboardInterrupt and doesn't run the script

Answer (score 10):

after every line put \ mark and press enter

Answer (score 7):

To code group of statements, `;\` will work

```
   list1=[1,2,3]
   list2=[4,5,6]

   print list1;\
   print list2
```

Will print both the lists

Where as, for `Indentation` statement, you need `:\`

```
  for i in list1:\
  print i
  //double enter
```

Will show all the elements in the list

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 3; print x ** 5
```

should help, but it doesnt matter that its executed the way it is in IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

Just open a new file: File > New window. You can run it by clicking run > run module.

Answer (score 0):

the `"\"` line at the end of the line works for me. in windows 10 cmd.

**Edit:** I've also noticed that you have to be consistent with its use, other wise you still get syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Go into editor mode with the F2 key. Depending on your terminal config this will put you in vim or nano. You can edit a snippet of code and then exit editor mode to get back to the ipython cli with your code and any newlines.