# Clearing the screen in IPython

Tags: python, windows, ipython

Is there a command in IPython to clear the screen?

**EDIT:** As @Saher mentions below, I can [clean the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432480/any-way-to-clear-python-shell) using `import os; os.system('CLS')`, but is there a way to do this without having to import all of `os`?

Comment: See the answers to the similar question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432480/any-way-to-clear-python-shell

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432480/any-way-to-clear-python-shell

Comment: you can also put an alias in your `ipy_user_conf.py` file.  i use this quite often so i have it aliased to `c` rather than having to type `!clear`.

Comment: I had to comment out this line from ~/.ipython/ipythonrc

 readline_parse_and_bind "\C-l": possible-completions 

After that it worked great

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To clear the screen on Windows, use `!CLS`.

On Unix-like systems, use `!clear`.

A shell command is executed by the operating system if prepended by an exclamation mark. See http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#system-shell-access.

Note that commands should also work without the exclamation mark if they are defined as aliases. See http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/shell.html?#aliases.

There is also a <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> shortcut for clearing the screen. See http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/shortcuts/index.html#single-filtered-shortcuts.

Comment: This one worked! I don't see anything regarding  `!CLS` in the link you provided though. Am I missing something?

Comment: The CLS command (or any command) is executed by the OS if prepended by an exclamation mark.

Comment: `Ctrl + L` works like a charm. Thanks !

Answer (score 15):

You can bind it to the common Ctrl-l shortcut by putting this into your `~/.ipython/ipythonrc`:

```
readline_parse_and_bind "\C-l": clear-screen
```

Comment: The command `clear-screen` does not seem to work on my system (Windows with Spyderlib), but I like the idea of binding a solution to `C-l`

Comment: For me, this line was already in my ipythonrc

    readline_parse_and_bind "\C-l": possible-completions

I had to comment it out, and then it worked great.

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for me on Windows

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> works in both `Windows` and `Ubuntu`. And I guess it's best because you don't have to type much.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe I'm just using a newer version, but it worked fine for me with just:

```
cls
```

On Windows, and on *nix:

```
clear
```

Answer (score 6):

for me, just to type "clear" is enought.

Comment: This works for me on Ubuntu (I assume almost all unix systems). However not on windows, but `!CLS` and `cls` works.

Answer (score 4):

clear is a default alias in ipython 0.11

```
In [76]: a = get_ipython()

In [77]: a.alias_manager.expand_alias('clear')
Out[77]: u'clear '
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running windows try `os.system('CLS')`

You need to import os first though:

```
import os
```

Comment: Thanks Saher, `import os; os.system('CLS')` seems to work (at least in Windows). Is there a way to do this without having to import all of `os` ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this without importing *os*

Answer (score 1):

In macOS 10.13.1, Terminal 2.8, press command-k for Clear to Start.

clear resulted in "NameError: name 'clear' is not defined."

Caution: As a noob I may not fully understand what I did, but command-k seemed to do what I intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
__import__('os').system("reset")
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows using Enthought Canopy Clear, CLS, !CLS, does not clear the previous data, it just moves all the data to above the top of the window.  If you scroll down the text is all there.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Powershell `cls` (in lowercase with no exclamation mark) clears the screen just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use ctrl + l in Windows 10 and it's works perfectly.

Comment: The ctrl + L shortcut has already been mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34330120)