# How to clear the screen of Interactive IPython console from Python code

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I have just migrated from Jupyter to Spyder. On the left of the screen there is a console that shows the output. When I rerun the code it keeps adding new lines. I want to start with a new screen. How?

PS1: When I go to the IPyhton console and write cls or clear, it works. But I want to do that from Python code. The latter doesn't recognize that command, but IPython console does!

PS2: I've tried

```
import os 
os.system('cls')  # on windows
```

It didn't work. It shows a CMD window for a moment and vanishes. But the console window in Spyder still shows the old errors, besides the new ones.

Comment: PS3: I can run the code after restarting the kernel. That's an obvious solution but I want something quick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clearing the screen in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892191/clearing-the-screen-in-ipython)

Comment: I've checked question. Didn't work. For what's worth, I'm running Spyder via Anaconda, and I have Windows.

Comment: use `!cls` and change the interpreter to `ipython` instead of the standard python interpreter `python`

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician Although I don't know how to do that, but you have correctly explained what's happening. Thanks, I will look up how to change the interpreter in Spyder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There are two ways to get what you want:

1. You can go to the menu `Run > Configuration per file` and select the option called `Execute in a dedicated console`. That option will clean your console after every execution.
2. Add the following code to your file:

   ```
   from IPython import get_ipython
   get_ipython.run_line_magic('clear', '')
   ```

Answer (score 2):

**Windows Spyder 4, Python 3.7:**

- `!cls`
- `cls`
- `cls()`
- `Ctrl + L`
- `clear`
- `clear()`
- `print(chr(27) + "[2J")`
- `print("\x1b[2J")`
- `clear-screen`

**Windows Terminal, Python 3.9:**

- `!cls`
- `cls`
- `Ctrl + L`
- `cls()`
- `print(chr(27) + "[2J")`
- `print("\x1b[2J")`

**Linux Terminal, Python 3.8:**

- `Ctrl + L`
- `clear`