# Why does print('\n') * 100 not work in Python 3.3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am attempting to clear lines of code in Python and came across a post at [Any way to clear python's IDLE window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432480/any-way-to-clear-python-shell) on how to do so however when I run the function below in IDLE 3.3 I get the error below. It does however work in version 2.7.3.

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    cls()
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 2, in cls
    print('\n') * 100
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

**CODE**

```
def cls():
    print('\n') * 100
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably mean

```
print('\n' * 100)
```

When you multiply a string by an int,  it is repeated:

```
>>> 'ha' * 3
'hahaha'
```

But what you do is multiply the value of `print('\n')` by `100`. But `print()` doesn't return anything (read: returns `None`), hence the error: you can't multiply `None` and `int`.

In Python 2 there is no difference, because there are no parentheses:

```
print '\n' * 100
```

Still, it's interpreted by Python the same way as in Python 3 (and not the same way you seem to iterpret it).

Comment: But isn't `NoneType` a string value? If so why can't it multiply `None * 100`

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey No, [`NoneType` is a special type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#the-null-object). There is only one object of this type and it's `None`. Strings have type `str`. Try `type(None)` and `type('hello')` in Python shell, for example. You need to distinguish `None` from the string `"None"`, of course.