# clear python idle using command

Tags: python, python-idle

I searched a lot but could not find any command to clear python idle(GUI)
can anyone help me and tell me if there is any command to clear the python IDLE.
Your help will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: As in clear the screen or clear the variables?

Comment: yes exactly the same way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to clear python's IDLE window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432480/any-way-to-clear-pythons-idle-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os` to clear the window if you're using command line. Note that the windows version does not work in Idle, only in the Python shell. If you are using windows, the best way might be to simply output the appropriate number of empty lines.

```
import os

os.system('clear')
os.system('CLS') # windows

# Solution for IDLE
N = 40 # you might need to adjust this
for i in range(N):
    print "\n"
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work in the Tkinter GUI that the OP is most probably referring to.

Comment: @SukritKalra Yep, I was editing my answer to answer just that.

Comment: Not working.. Running the loop does not clear the screen. It just puts blank space on the screen. Anyways thanks for the try.

Comment: @NelsonMenezes putting empty lines is the only way as far as I can tell, of clearing IDLE. Perhaps if you post **why** you need to  clear the screen, you might get better responses.

Comment: @Dhara wanted a command that could behave as the command clrscr() in C. I wanted it so that I could start with a fresh screen every time I run a program.

Comment: @NelsonMenezes The clrscr is probably useful when running an interactive session. If running a script, simply close the window before running a program it will open a fresh window again.