# how to clear the screen of the idle3(python3 shell)?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I used some of the codes such as
`clear` `cls` `clc` but none of them gave me the desired result.
Is there any command that can clear the screen of the idle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to clear python's IDLE window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432480/any-way-to-clear-pythons-idle-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a temporary hack to achieve the effect of a clear screen in IDLE Python 3 shell. It is:

```
print ("\n" * 100)
```

Answer (score -2):

Press the key
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

then you can restart the powershell.
Just like the 'clear' used in terminal, it clears the all variables you've assigned values for.