# How to clear screen on python 3.6 IDLE?

Tags: python, python-idle

All I wanted to ask that if i want to clear screen in IDLE what method I can use to clear it without closing it.
For e.g.
I print this statement using:-

```
print("Prabal Tiwari")
```

after getting output of this I want to clear the console without closing it.
Just like we use "clear" on ubuntu terminal.

Comment: What do you mean? Please describe clearly

Comment: This is a duplicate of a duplicate...  Search in SO search box for `[python-idle] clear screen` to find multiple questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "cls" and "clear" are commands which will clear a terminal (ie a DOS prompt, or terminal window). From your screenshot, you are using the shell within IDLE, which won't be affected by such things. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to clear the screen in IDLE. The best you could do is to scroll the screen down lots of lines, eg:

```
print "\n" * 100
```

Though you could put this in a function:

```
def cls(): print "\n" * 100
```

And then call it when needed as `cls()`

source: [Any way to clear python's IDLE window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432480/any-way-to-clear-pythons-idle-window)

Comment: I've been trying to put this into a function and have it called on start-up but have been running around in circles in trying to get the function called with the environmental variable (Mac OSX). Any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677593/how-do-i-import-my-user-defined-function-without-having-to-call-the-py-file-it

Answer (score 0):

I think you can restart it but I don't think there is any way to do it without restarting the console. Hope this helped!