# How do I import my user-defined function without having to call the .py file it is in?

Tags: python-idle

To solve the problem of the (Python) IDLE not having a built-in "clear" function, I created a user-defined function [cls()], that I have stored in a functions.py file in my sys.path.

```
import sys, functions
```

My user-defined function works, but I do not prefer always typing in:

```
functions.cls()
```

***Amendment after Terry's comment***

How do I reference my `functions.py` file with my environmental variable IDLESTARTUP? I have tried the aforementioned by editing my .bash_profile with: $IDLESTARTUP="/Users/Mac/Documents/functions.py" export $IDLESTARTUP and starting up my IDLE using the command with the appropriate flag (idle3.6 -s). [Note: comment image added above in the original question, for reference]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qejuF.png)

How can I make it so I only have to type in my user-defined function, and not my .py file name?

```
cls()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the beginning of section 3 of the IDLE doc, available both online and as Help => IDLE Help.
"Upon startup with the -s option, IDLE will execute the file referenced by the environment variables IDLESTARTUP or PYTHONSTARTUP. IDLE first checks for IDLESTARTUP; if IDLESTARTUP is present the file referenced is run.  If IDLESTARTUP is not present, IDLE checks for PYTHONSTARTUP.  Files referenced by these environment variables are convenient places to store functions that are used frequently from the IDLE shell, or for executing import statements to import common modules."

In addition, `-r file` will run the file.

Currently, the startup files are not rerun when one restarts the Shell.

Comment: How do I reference my `functions.py` file with my environmental variable IDLESTARTUP? I have tried the aforementioned by editing my .bash_profile with: $IDLESTARTUP="/Users/Mac/Documents/functions.py" export $IDLESTARTUP and starting up my IDLE using the command with the appropriate flag (idle3.6 -s). [Note: comment image added above in the original question, for reference]

Comment: On Windows, I just did `set IDLESTARTUP=f:/python/a/tem2.py` followed by `python -m idlelib -s` and tem2 (`print("STARTUP")` was run before the `>>>` prompt appeared.  I don't know the *nix/Mac way to set environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to import cls this way:

`from functions import cls`

Then you can call the method this way:

`cls()`