# How to clear the screen in IDLE on iMac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, screen, python-idle

After hours of exercises I want to clear the screen to remove the debris above. 
I am using IDLE as the shell. Any hope?

Research Research Research.

I can find none that work on the iMac.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to clear python's IDLE window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432480/any-way-to-clear-pythons-idle-window)

Answer (score 0):

Are you on linux? It's the only os that can clear IDLE, as far as I'm aware:

```
import os
os.system('clear')
```

Of course, there's always the goofy option:

```
print("\n") * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no built in functionality for this in idle. You can sort of “clear” it by printing a bunch of new lines though.

```
print(‘\n’*80)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works now on any system, not just Mac: open an editor window if there is not one already (new, untitled, is OK), close Shell, in the editor, click Run => Python Shell or Run Module (F5).

Adding something more direct has been [discussed for a decade](https://bugs.python.org/issue6143), but with no agreement on the various technical issues.  I am thinking now of adding a "Clear and Restart" item to the Shell menu that would irreversibly clear Shell's window, keep the statement history, and restart the execution process (which is what 'Restart Shell' does).