# I want to clear the previous code in python

Tags: python, python-idle

So I have this code and immediately after the code is completed I want to clear the screen and run another code automatically, please how do I do this?

```
def load():
    n("Loading")
    for load in range(1,4):
        n(".")
        time.sleep(1)


load()
```

Comment: What do you mean with the screen? Do you mean the terminal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to clear python's IDLE window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432480/any-way-to-clear-pythons-idle-window)

Comment: all the stuff there doesn't work all it does is print 100 new lines or doesn't work at all, does it work in python 3.7

Comment: @Curris How about you then write a better question where you explain that you are working with python 3.7 and want the clear the idle window instead of the screen?

Comment: `for x in range(1, 4):         n('.')         time.sleep(1)     print('\n' * 100)` just moves down 100 line or you can change how many you want (tested in python3.7)

Comment: There is no environment-independent way to clear a window unless you use a cross-platform GUI framework such as tkinter, which wraps tcl/tk.  To load and read another file, use `with open('somefile.py') as f\n  exec(f.read())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear the output of the script use following on Windows:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

Or this for Linux/MacOS

```
import os
os.system('clear')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

Comment: i am using python shell and it doesn't work i do not know y

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [Introduction to python](http://introtopython.org/terminal_apps.html#Clearing-the-screen)

```
import os

# Show a simple message.
print("I like climbing mountains.")

# Clear the screen.
os.system('clear')
```

In the above example, you will see no "I like climbing mountains." because as soon as the message is displayed the terminal will be cleared.

**Note:** The command to clear the terminal screen is different on Windows. The command `os.system('cls')` should work.

Comment: that code is only working in command prompt not in python-idle