# How do I clear printed text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, printing, console

I'm having trouble with clearing text in python 3.8. I've looked at similar answers but they didn't help me with the problem I'm having since the solutions those answers offered did not work for me. here's the line of code:

```
def userInstructions(userInput):
    if userInput == "help" or userInput == "Help":
        help()
    elif userInput == "list" or userInput == "List":
        words()
    elif userInput == "tutorial" or userInput == "Tutorial":
        tutorial()
    elif userInput == "salve":
        LatinRef.salve()

    return input('\nEnter your responce: ')
    os.system('clear')
```

What I want this to do is every time the user inputs a response that response would be cleared and it would be blank instead of appearing like this:

```
Type in your command or any Latin word to review or learn.

Enter your responce: hello
Type in your command or any Latin word to review or learn.

Enter your response: help
```

how can I fix this? I'm currently using python 3.8 if that helps.

Comment: What OS is this running in?

Comment: This is my first time using os so I don't really know but I'm using it in python 3.8. @gdanton

Comment: If it is windows you have to use 'cls'

Comment: @gdanton I'm using MacOs

Comment: Try 
clear = lambda: os.system('clear')
clear()

Comment: There has to be new line character, the comment here is now showing it. I will post as an answer.

Comment: The `os.system('clear')` in your code is never executed because the `return input('\nEnter your responce: ')` right before it exits the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/518007/1244045

```
clear = lambda: os.system('clear')
clear()
```

'cls' for windows.

Comment: `Type in your command or any Latin word to review or learn.

Enter your responce: he
Type in your command or any Latin word to review or learn.

Enter your responce: help
Type in your command or any Latin word to review or learn.
list of commands
help = Display of commands
list = list of all the Latin I vocabulary
tutorial = in depth tutorial
Quit = exits the main program to the exit credits and then exits the app


Enter your responce: Quit`

Comment: still the result I want to avoid it just putting itself on another line

Comment: Hmm.. Wierd. Is the Python installed in MacOS and you are running the program from terminal?

Comment: I'm running the program through python IDL but once I'm finished would turn it into a separate app. I got python3.8 from the python website

Comment: Ok, that might be problem. Can you try running from terminal?

Comment: sure, it would take a while since this program I'm creating is using three files so it will take me some time.

Comment: Ok, it should work. If you want to do from interface the only way seems to be faking it by printing new line characters - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432480/any-way-to-clear-pythons-idle-window

Comment: I actually did something wrong when using your code. I saw a comment in this question and I realized that I've put it in the wrong area so now it works. Thank you and sorry if I wasted your time.

Comment: No worries. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Script to clear screen based on the os

```
from os import name, system

# windows
if name == 'nt':
    system('cls')
# linux
else:
    system('clear')
```

Comment: Always add explanations to you answers.