# Alternative for os.system('cls') for python on mac

Tags: python

I am trying to make a stopwatch where I use os to clear the terminal for the ticking numbers, but os.system('cls') does not work on idle or on mac. Are there any alternatives I can use? I usually use repl because I am doing this for class.

Comment: Refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432480/any-way-to-clear-pythons-idle-window

Comment: Hi John, `os.system('cls')` is specifically for Windows, for Mac have you tried using `os.system('clear')` instead?

Comment: Yes, os.system('clear') was not working either. I appreciate the response!

Answer (score 0):

`os.system('clear')` is the alternative for macOS and repl, however on repl you could also `import replit` and then call `replit.clear()` to clear the terminal.

Comment: NIce! Thank you, I have been looking all over for something like this!