# Clearing the screen of IDLE interactive mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

Can I clear the screen of IDLE interactive mode in Windows? I tried with the following code which fails to work:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

The cls command works only in Windows terminal(command prompt) and it doesn't work in IDLE screen.

Is there any other way? Or first of all, is there any hope to clear that IDLE interactive mode???

Comment: Unfortunately (after taking a peek at IDLE's internals too), it looks like there is no way to clear the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cls` and `clear` are commands which will clear a terminal (ie a DOS prompt, or terminal window). If you are using the shell within IDLE, which won't be affected by such things, a workaround might be to print a lot of empty lines with `print("\n" * 100)`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433818/5015356) for more information.

Comment: Did you just copy/paste this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433818/12479639

Comment: @axe319 Hey, as long as it works and helps the one who asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can `from os import system` and then `system("cls")`
this will just clear out the screen. have fun coding:).

Comment: This is doing exactly what OP said does not work.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible, neither in IDLE, nor in Python command prompt.

Use [IPython](http://USK@EsJ5sVF%7EBMC8%7E99FgM6pylmTaUW4I5c8u76Hu%7EJXnIs,Mgar%7EuEa9R-kyeCmaaaSVyJKuV%7EaxW3i22rguUmIV-U,AQACAAE/TheBest/80/) instead with its “magic” command `%cls` (and many others), preferable as a part of some IDE which utilized it, for example [Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder), [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) or [JupyterLab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab).

[Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) contains both Spyder and JupyterLab and many Python packages, it's probably the best all-in-one solution.