# How to clear the console without cleaning the variable values in python?

Tags: python

After entering data and displayed something, I want to get clear the console.
eg:-

```
num1=int(input('Number 1: '))
print(num1)
```

Then in the next code line, I want to clear the console to next process, without cleaning the `num1` variable value.

This is the java method that can solve my problem. I want the python code as this.

```
public final static void clearConsole() {
         try {
             final String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
             if (os.contains("Windows")) {
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
             } else {
                 System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
                 System.out.flush();
             }
         } catch (final Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         // Handle any exceptions.
         }
    }
```

Comment: and clear the console between the entering data and the print?

Comment: only print  and inputting prints @Nehuel Brandan

Comment: are you looking for `os.system('cls')`? (or `os.system('clc')` on Linux)

Comment: @M.A I don't know what `clc` should be on Linux, but `clear` does the job for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console)

Comment: no its not. I want to get the variable values too

Comment: Check my answer. I get the variable values too.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch Good spot, my brain was in Matlab mode :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean something like this?

```
import os

num1=int(input('Number 1: '))
_ = os.system("clear")

print(num1)
```

cleaning the console between the entering data and the print.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `os` module for this. `cls` is the clear console command for windows. If you are using a Linux distro it will be `clear`

```
import os

num1 = int(input('Number 1: '))
print(num1)

os.system("cls")

print(num1)
```

When I run this, I still can access the value of the variable `num1`

Comment: Check that thread > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432480/any-way-to-clear-pythons-idle-window There is no way you can clear the console of an IDLE. Run your script from terminal as `python your_script.py`