# Clear command line output from Python [Eclipse]

Tags: python, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse for writing Python, and I want to be able to easily clear the screen. I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-python-interpreter-console), and tried (among other things suggested there) the following solution

```
import os

def clear():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

but it doesn't entirely solve my problem. Instead of clearing the screen, the routine prints a small square (as if wanting to print an unknown character) to the command output window in Eclipse.

Typing `cls` in the command line works perfectly fine, as does running a Python script with the above code from command line. But how can I make it look nice in Eclipse as well?

Comment: did you try '`clear`' instead of '`cls`' within the Eclipse console? (just to check)

Comment: I did - since this line of code runs an os command, I get the same error message I would if I'd type 'cls' it in command prompt: "'cls' is not a known command..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with running it in Eclipse is that [cls](https://ss64.com/nt/cls.html) uses [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to clear the screen. What I mean by this is that to clear the screen, `cls` writes a string such as `"\033[[80;j"` to the output buffer. The native console (the one outside of Eclipse) interprets this as a command to clear the screen, but the Eclipse console doesn't understand it, so it just prints a small square as if printing an unknown character.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing in outputs is actually not possible. The best hack is to print full of line breaks.
IDEs like Eclipse never simulate terminals properly.

Answer (score 0):

As it's just an [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) problem, I suppose it will not affect your final product if you want to clean your final users' screen.

While for the Eclipse environment, there is a little button in top-right of the console screen which enables you from cleaning it.