# Ascii art that is continually replaced

Tags: python, ascii

I want to make a simple game in Python where you are the '@' sign and can move around a 
room.

```
level = """
  ┌-------------------------------------------┐
  |                                           |
  |                                           |
  |                                           |
  |                                           |
  |                                           |
  |                                           |
  |                    @                      |
  |                                           |
  |                                           |
  |                                           |
  |                                           |
  |                                           |
  |                                           |
  |                                           |
  └-------------------------------------------┘
"""
print level
moving = raw_input(' ')
if moving == str('w'):
    level == """
 ┌-------------------------------------------┐
 |                                           |
 |                                           |
 |                                           |
 |                                           |
 |                                           |
 |                    @                      |
 |                                           |
 |                                           |
 |                                           |
 |                                           |
 |                                           |
 |                                           |
 |                                           |
 |                                           |
 └-------------------------------------------┘
   """
    print level
```

That is my code so far.
I want to make it so that when the user inputs 'w'
the first 'level' printed is replaced in the terminal.
Is this possible?
If so how do I do this?
If not how (alternatively) would I do this?
[edit]
when i input 'w' i want it to replace the first 'level' printed in the program. instead of printing out a new instance of 'level' sorry for not explaining well enough

Comment: Do you've any specific problem?

Comment: yes when i input 'w' i want it to replace the first 'level' printed in the program. instead of printing out a new instance of 'level'            sorry for not explaining well enough

Comment: You should use some library like [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) to avoid re-printing the whole screen each time.

Comment: any tutorial on how to do this? (in curses)

Comment: and could I use curses for say a text adventure to display statistics such as health e.t.c.   on the side of the terminal?

Comment: oh and how could i make it so the '@' cannot collide with the wall?

Comment: could i just make it so when the player tries to collide the @ with the wall it just dosent do anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) module provide a way to create TUIs(Terminal User Interfaces). You can find a tutorial [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html).

A small example related to what you want to do:

```
import curses
curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()    # don't echo the keys on the screen
curses.cbreak()    # don't wait enter for input

window = curses.newwin(10, 10, 0, 0)  # create a 10x10 window
window.box()       # Draw the box outside the window
cur_x = 1
cur_y = 1
while True:
    window.addch(cur_y, cur_x, '@')
    window.refresh()
    inchar = window.getch()
    window.addch(cur_y, cur_x, ' ')
    # W,A,S,D used to move around the @
    if inchar == ord('w'):
        cur_y -= 1
    elif inchar == ord('a'):
        cur_x -= 1
    elif inchar == ord('d'):
        cur_x += 1
    elif inchar == ord('s'):
        cur_y += 1
    elif inchar == ord('q'):
        # stop the program when Q is entered.
        break
curses.endwin()
```

Save it in a file `test_curses.py` then run:

```
python test_curses.py
```

In the terminal and use WASD to move around the `@`.

Comment: and how would i add static text using curses? that stays there even if the program is scrolling down?

Comment: @user2487886 It depends on what you mean. Probably the cleaniest way is to simply put the text in a different window.

Comment: but could i display it in the terminal? like on the side? like a rougelike

Comment: @user2487886 Yes. Curses is *the* library used to write rogue-like programs.

Comment: so curses isn't in the default python right? where do u download the library?

Comment: because when i try running your code it says it cannot import curses     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/curses_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import curses
  File "C:\Python27\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ImportError: No module named _curses

Comment: @user2487886 Which operating system are you using? Python `curses` is a standard library module, but on some OS the `ncurses` C-library isn't installed by default and hence the module cannot be used. If you are on windows you should check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244897/curses-like-library-for-cross-platform-console-app-in-python) question and answers, since the normal curses library doesn't work there.

Comment: Downloads for Windows are available at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 0):

I've never used curses (as mentioned by Bakuriu), but the ability to change a character on the screen without changing anything else on the screen would make all this much easier.

As a workaround, I'd recommend you just clear the screen between instances:

```
import os
os.system('clear')
```

EDIT: Curses uses the `move(x,y)` command to position the cursor at any location required, and if you don't want the cursor to be displayed, you can use `curs_set(False)`.
(http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/curses.html)

Comment: `clear` will only work on unix-like systems. Windows uses `cls` for that (if I remember correctly).

Comment: thnx, but i also want to add static text like health etc                 is this only achievable with curses

Comment: and btw im using windows 7

Comment: Fine, then: `os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')` (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466866/)

Comment: Sorry. You had mentioned 'terminal' in the question, so I assumed Linux. My bad.

Comment: i meant the python terminal