# How to make a script execute just after python shell starts and before customuer's input?

Tags: python, shell, import, pythonxy

In Pythonxy I can edit some python scripts in an pre-defined folder so that they will be executed (or import? I don't know). For example, if I put a script in that folder:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
```

Then after I enter python shell, I can conveniently use np and sp as quick references.

Now the problem is, how can I use such technique without Pythonxy's support in standard python shell? Can I write a script to handle pre import? I think it will be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting up a python startup file, and set `PYTHONSTARTUP` variable to that file. In the startup file, just write

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
```

Then, every time you enter python shell, it will automatically import the above modules.

Here is an example. [Installing pythonstartup file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837259/installing-pythonstartup-file)