# Can I import default Python modules in a Python Docker image?

Tags: python, docker, python-import

I am new to Docker, and as a learning exercise, I want to make a custom Python package available through a Docker image. The package is called `hashtable-nicolerg` and includes a `HashTable` class that can be imported with `from hashtable_nicolerg.hashtable import HashTable`.

It is straightforward to create an image with additional Python packages installed:

1. Write a Dockerfile

   ```
   # Dockerfile
   FROM python:3
   RUN pip install --no-cache-dir hashtable-nicolerg
   ```
2. Build the image

   ```
   docker build -t python-hashtable .
   ```

However, the goal, which I realize is hardly an abundant use-case for Docker images, is **for the user to be able to create `HashTable` instances as soon as the container's Python prompt starts**.

Specifically, this is the current behavior:

```
$ docker run -it python-hashtable
Python 3.11.0 (main, Nov 15 2022, 19:58:01) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> hash_table = HashTable(capacity=100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'HashTable' is not defined
>>> from hashtable_nicolerg.hashtable import HashTable
>>> hash_table = HashTable(capacity=100)
```

And this is the desired behavior:

```
$ docker run -it python-hashtable
Python 3.11.0 (main, Nov 15 2022, 19:58:01) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> hash_table = HashTable(capacity=100)
```

I don't want my imaginary users to have to type `from hashtable_nicolerg.hashtable import HashTable` every time they run a container from this image. So, is it possible for me to effectively run `from hashtable_nicolerg.hashtable import HashTable` within my Docker image so that users don't have to manually import this module?

Again, I realize this is not the most popular use-case for a Docker image. I'm using this as an exercise to learn more about Python and Docker. I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the [`PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837259/installing-pythonstartup-file) exists and is the name of a valid Python file, then that file will be executed when any new Python shell starts up.

So whether you want to do this in a Docker container or on your local machine, it works the same way. Define `PYTHONSTARTUP` (in `.bashrc`, for instance) and then write a startup file.

```
# .bashrc
export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.python_startup
```

```
# .python_startup
from hashtable_nicolerg.hashtable import HashTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Silvio Mayolo for the answer! Here is a Docker alternative to exporting an environment variable from `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir hashtable-nicolerg

WORKDIR /
COPY .python_startup .
ENV PYTHONSTARTUP=./.python_startup
```

Then after building the image with `docker build -t python-hashtable .`, I get the desired behavior:

```
$ docker run -it python-hashtable
Python 3.11.0 (main, Nov 15 2022, 19:58:01) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> hash_table = HashTable(capacity=100)
```