# How to run python file in cmd?

Tags: python, cmd

I installed the **Python 3.4** in C drive.
And add `Environment variable` as **C:\Python34.**
I save a python program in **C>users>python>first.py.**
I open cmd and enter command like this

```
C:\users\python>python first.py
```

Then showing an error

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can i resolve this..I am totally confused..Please help me..
**My OS is windows 8**

Comment: `C:\Python3.4` must be added to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I try like this C:\users\python>first.py then it worked

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4209102/355230) which shows setting an environment variable on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it working properly, you must add `;C:\Python34` on the end of the `Path` (or `PATH`) enviroment variable.  I don't think `C:\Python3.4` would work.  The environment variables can be changed by going to: `Control Panel > System > Advanced (tab) > Environment Variables`.

Comment: its a typo added ;C:\Python34

Answer (score 0):

Go to the environment variables window, and edit the Path system variables, add the C:\Python3.4 into your path variable

[image]