# Windows Task Schedule will not run .py file

Tags: python, windows, windows-task-scheduler

I have received a ton of errors trying to run my py script via task scheduler. This is on my personal computer and all files are on local drives. The last error I get is The System cannot find the file specified. Even when I move the file to my desktop

Script: ‪C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe

Argument: Bot.py

Start in: ‪C:\Users\S\Desktop\Bot.py

There is nothing else on my desktop. I have no idea what the issue could be. I am running on highest permissions and I have deselected the Ac power checkbox. I am at a loss and any help would be appreciated. It took me a really long time to get the script right and find python on my PC but I think this error has to do with the py file itself.

Comment: 'Start in' should be a directory, not a file name. Just a hint: Try to use full paths always. Make sure the 'task' is executed in the use 'S' context.

Comment: ‪I changed start in to this: C:\Users\S\Desktop\ and still get the same error. I am new to this but I think I am using full paths am i not?

Comment: It's just `bot.py` as argument :)

Comment: Even though the file is saved with a capital "B"? I have tried quotes and no quotes on that to no avail in the argument field.

Comment: Keep the capital 'B', sorry i didnt want to confuse you.

Comment: Got it. Still get the same error after those changes. Very odd.

Comment: It may have something to do with the task not being run with the right credentials. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4209102/355230).