# How can I add project directory to PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, shell, sh

Contents of my project is like this

```
C:/{user_name}/my_project/
│  bar.sh
├─scripts/
│  │  bar.sh
│  │
│  └─bar/
│     bar.sh
│
└─src/
    foo.py
```

and
Content of all of bar.sh is

```
python src/foo.py
```

so if I run from C:/{user_name}/my_project/ directory, bar.sh works.

```
bash bash.sh 
bash scripts/bar.sh 
bash scripts/bar/bar.sh
```

However, after moved to scripts directory, below command does not work because bar.sh tries to find `/my_project/sciprts/src/foo.py`

```
bash bar.sh
```

I understand we can add my_project directory to PYTHONPATH by editing window's envrionmental valiables to solve this. However, I would like to avoid this because {user_name} can be varied and this envrionmental is shared by many guys.

Therefore I am looking for a good way to add my_project directory to PYTHONPATH by adding **same** line(s) to bar.sh. Do you know such a magic command?

Comment: Why not just modify the line of code to call `python ../src/foo.py`?

Comment: If I want to get into the parent directory of my script in Bash, I usually use `cd "$(dirname "$0")/.."`. Dunno if that works on Windows, though.

Comment: I don't think adding a new directory to the `PYTHONPATH` is the solution here. Instead, I would modify your `bar.sh` to add the `src` directory to `PATH` and then call `python foo.py` directly

Comment: Thank you for your comments!
Actual project is more complicated like import modules mutually, so I would like to resolve this just editting sh
Nick's comment works for me!

Comment: Windows has two levels of environment variables — User and System. Just define `PYTHONPATH` at a System level variable because that doesn't vary depending on the user name. Here's an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4209102/355230) of mine on the topic (although exactly how to do things has changed). Here's [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208659/when-to-use-sys-path-append-and-when-modifying-pythonpath-is-enough/4209102#4209102).

Comment: You may be able to simply put the path in a .pth path configuration file in the right directory as described near the beginning of site module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#module-site). This will add the path in the file to sys.path at every Python startup (it it exists) — so you wouldn't need to do anything in your bash script (although I suppose you could have it add the `.pth` file and remove it after running `src/foo.py`).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't think modifying `PYTHONPATH` via bash script is a good solution here as you risk corrupting it. If you're interested in being able to call `python foo.py` directly, you should turn `/src` into a package. Not only will this allow you to execute `foo.py` from anywhere in your system, you will also be able to import the code therein into any Python code you write. Here's some documentation on [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) and some more on [creating packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Essentially, you create some files in you `my_project` directory to tell Python about the package itself as well as dependencies and such. Make sure that all the directories in the `/src` directory have an `__init__.py` file as well. Once you've done that, you can call `pip insall -e my_project` which will install it as a package on your system (make sure you have pip installed; it should have been when you installed Python, but if not you can get it [here](https://pypi.org/project/pip/)). After that, you can call your code from wherever.

Answer (score 0):

`cd "$(dirname "$0")/.."`
works for me!