# word.SaveAs() - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SaveAs' - When ran with Task Scheduler

Tags: python, docx, win32com, windows-task-scheduler

I'm running into a strange problem and I'm very lost on what could be happening.  The general background is I'm looping through a folder and converting all the '.docx' files into '.pdf' files.  The part that is confusing is that when I enter the `for` loop, it no longer works correctly when trigger via Windows Task Scheduler without explicitly re-writing the file path.  I am using the Windows Task Scheduler as my user (Admin rights) and with logged on or off status, with highest privilege's.  This is the same user I'm using when triggering manually.  This is on an RDP server.

Here is more details below:

Script 1: Works when triggered with Task Scheduler

```
from win32com import client
import os
import sys

#import Custom Classes
Classes = r'C:\Python_Solutions\Classes'

#Direct import to Class file
sys.path.insert(0,Classes)

import Classes

#Declare jobName
jobName = 'pdfsave'
logFolderLocation = r'C:\Python_Solutions\Notice_Form_Generation\pdftest'

#Create Log Folder
Classes.Atlas.createTextJobLog(jobName, logFolderLocation)

try:
    print('before')
    for file in os.listdir(r'C:\Python_Solutions\Notice_Form_Generation\Local\2022-01-01\1_FixedPrem1stAttempt'):
        print(str(file))
        if '.docx' in file:
            filepath = r'C:\Python_Solutions\Notice_Form_Generation\Local\2022-01-01\1_FixedPrem1stAttempt\\' + file
            print('Converting to .pdf: ' + filepath)
            endFilePath_pdf = filepath[:-4] + 'pdf'
            print('here1')
            word = client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
            print('here2')
            worddoc = word.Documents.Open(filepath, ReadOnly=1)
            print('here3')
            worddoc.SaveAs(endFilePath_pdf, FileFormat=17)
            print('here4')
            worddoc.Close()
            print('here5')
            word.Quit()
            print('here6')
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Script 2: Works when I trigger or run the script myself, but fails with the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SaveAs'`, when I run with the task scheduler.  I am confused how this could be, as you can see in the code, I am double checking the file paths to make sure they are being fed into the functions correctly but it doesn't want to work..

It breaks after `here3` during the `.SaveAs()` function:

```
from win32com import client
import os
import sys

#import Custom Classes
Classes = r'C:\Python_Solutions\Classes'

#Direct import to Class file
sys.path.insert(0,Classes)

import Classes


#Declare jobName
jobName = 'pdfsave_simple2'
logFolderLocation = r'C:\Python_Solutions\Notice_Form_Generation\pdftest'


# In[ ]:


#Create Log Folder
Classes.Atlas.createTextJobLog(jobName, logFolderLocation)

folder = r'C:\Python_Solutions\Notice_Form_Generation\Local\2022-01-01\1_FixedPrem1stAttempt'

try:
    print('before')
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        print(str(file))
        if '.docx' in file:
            filepath = folder + '\\' + file
            print('Converting to .pdf: ' + filepath)
            endFilePath_pdf = filepath[:-4] + 'pdf'
            print('here1')
            word = client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
            print('here2')

            print(os.path.abspath(filepath))
            print(os.path.abspath(endFilePath_pdf))

            worddoc = word.Documents.Open(filepath, ReadOnly=1)
            print('here3')
            worddoc.SaveAs(endFilePath_pdf, FileFormat=17)  # <-- here3
            print('here4')
            worddoc.Close()
            print('here5')
            word.Quit()
            print('here6')
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.exit()
```

Things I have tried with Script 2:

--- Adding the abs path into the function (I get the same error):

```
worddoc = word.Documents.Open(os.path.abspath(filepath), ReadOnly=1)
worddoc.SaveAs(os.path.abspath(endFilePath_pdf), FileFormat=17)
```

--- Tried to recreate the file path with the `r'example\example` before sending into the word functions (This actually broke with the same error when I tried running manually):

```
filepath = "r'" + os.path.abspath(filepath) + "'"
endFilePath_pdf = "r'" + os.path.abspath(endFilePath_pdf) + "'"
```

--- When I check the directory, they are both the same when I run manually and when I run with the scheduler:

```
pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
```

I believe this is what is wrong, can anyone help (detailed below)

When I tried the following locally, I get:

```
            print('cwd: ' + str(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())))
            print('script run: ' + str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()))
```

- cwd: `C:\Python_Solutions\Notice_Form_Generation\pdftest`
- script run: `C:\Python_Solutions\Notice_Form_Generation\pdftest`

When I run with the Task Scheduler, I get

- cwd: `C:\Windows\system32`
- script run: `C:\Python_Solutions\Notice_Form_Generation\pdftest`

I changed the cwd with the following and still get the same `NoneType` error:

```
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)
```

Is there something I am missing?  It is so strange to me that I am inputting the same exact string into the function in both circumstances, and it even works when triggered manually, but when triggered through the task scheduler I get the `NoneType` error!  I have no idea what could be going on, do I have to write the path more specifically somehow when am running with task scheduler?  Or maybe make sure I am in the right cwd before going into it?  I am dumbfounded because I found it works when I write the file path in the for loop, but I need to iterate through multiple folders, so I need the ability to not write explicitly the folder path in the `for` loop.  I am using the loop to get through many folders and files (in the larger scale case of this script).

Update - I tried using comtypes.client and it fails with NULL COM pointer access before step 3

````
            print('1')
            word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
            print('2')
            doc = word.Documents.Open(filepath)
            print('3')
            doc.SaveAs(endFilePath_pdf, FileFormat=17)
            print('4')
            doc.Close()
            print('1')
            word.Quit()
    ```
````

Comment: It looks to me like the `word.Documents.Open(filepath, ReadOnly=1)` call is what is failing (and returning `None`). Since `folder` is an absolute path, the current working directory shouldn't matter. That said, I believe there is a way to set what the cwd is when creating a task in the Task Scheduler, so try configuring it to be same as it is when you run it manually. Another thing you can try is checking for the file to be opened existence using `os.path.exists()` before calling `Open()`. However if it says it doesn't exist and the path is valid, I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Hi @martineau,  os.path.exists(filepath) = True when placed above.  I may try a different libraries because I am lost..

The endfildpath is False, because that's because it hasn't been created yet.  I may try 

import aspose.words as aw or pywin32 or something.. thanks for all the help and any future help.  This is such an annoying problem...

Comment: @martineau I tried running using import comtypes.client
```
            print('1')
            word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
            print('2')
            doc = word.Documents.Open(filepath)
            print('3')
            doc.SaveAs(endFilePath_pdf, FileFormat=17)
            print('4')
            doc.Close()
            print('5')
            word.Quit()
```
Fails before print 3 with NULL COM pointer access.  So fails on the .Open().  Just wanted to send more info over as it may give insight

Comment: All that proves is that the `word.Documents.Open(filepath)` call is failing and returning `NULL` (instead of `None`) (as I already mentioned).

Comment: @martineau Is there a way I can see the results printed out of the word.Documents.Open(filepath), to see if it's NULL/None and not an actual file?  I wonder if the script just isn't opening Word.Application

Comment: You ought be able to output the result to text file that you can read afterwards. Don't give the text file an absolute path, just some unique file name. You may have to search for the file after running a test to determine its location.

Comment: Why are you creating and destroying the Word application dispatch object on each iteration of the loop? That is pretty inefficient. Also try `ReadOnly=True`. The number 1 is not necessarily interpreted as Boolean true by Word.

Comment: @martineau how would I go about that?  Would it be something like, before step 3, do something like "with open('test.txt', 'w') as f: f.write('test')"?

Comment: @DS_London Thanks for the input.  I can look into not opening and closing word each time (but also that is a side concern at the moment).  In addition, I can try the ReadOnly=True but since I know it's already working when I use it, it should work the same with an unattended user

Comment: *After* the `worddoc = word.Documents.Open(…)` line, add a `with open('debug_me.txt', 'w') as dbfile:`, then an indented `dbfile.write(f'{worddoc=}\n')`.

Comment: Hi @martineau, when I run locally, the document says 'worddoc=<COMObject Open>', when I run with windows scheduler, it doesn't create the document

Comment: @martineau I found out some more debugging.  When 'Run whether user is logged on or not' is checked, the error is created.  When I run with 'Run only when user is logged on', the script works..  I'm not sure this helps much but just noticed it as well

Comment: Hi @martineau I just wanted to say thanks for all the help.  I am giving up and found a sort of sloppier solution.  I left it on as triggered with user logged on and found out I can have the user stay logged in the RDP forever (I have it set to 5 days and will change to 14 most likely once I know it's been running for awhile) without having to log back in.

Do you know a more efficient way to loop through and leave word open and only close once the loop is done?  I only want to open it IF it found a .docx file..  As mentioned by DS

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I am having the same NoneType error when using a scheduled task as logged off user that runs python to save a docx as a PDF on Windows Server 2022 and Windows 10 Pro.

Oddly, it is working as expected on Windows 11.

Unfortunately, I have not yet figured out why. Thanks to OP for confirming I was not losing my mind. Will update if I find solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by modifying docx2pdf **init**.py:

Imported pythoncom, then in the "windows" method i have added pythoncom.CoInitialize() as argument to both SavesAs calls.