# problem is using progress bar with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tqdm

I'd like to add a progress bar to my calculation in Jupyter notebook. I'm using `tqdm` to do that. Here is the code I have

```
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

df.progress_apply(lambda c: ...)
```

but it gives me the following error message

```
if name in self._info_axis:
2743                 return self[name]
2744             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
2745 
2746     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_is_builtin_func'
```

What's the problem?

Comment: I don't know if it is still up to date, but this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45600503/9274732) may be interesting for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use tqdm with pandas in a jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476680/how-to-use-tqdm-with-pandas-in-a-jupyter-notebook)