# Add months to a date in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm trying to figure out how to add 3 months to a date in a Pandas dataframe, while keeping it in the date format, so I can use it to lookup a range.

This is what I've tried:

```
#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Timestamp('20161011'),
                   pd.Timestamp('20161101') ], columns=['date'])

#create a future month period
plus_month_period = 3

#calculate date + future period
df['future_date'] = plus_month_period.astype("timedelta64[M]")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You could use [`pd.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html)

```
In [1756]: df.date + pd.DateOffset(months=plus_month_period)
Out[1756]:
0   2017-01-11
1   2017-02-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

Details

```
In [1757]: df
Out[1757]:
        date
0 2016-10-11
1 2016-11-01

In [1758]: plus_month_period
Out[1758]: 3
```

Comment: @Ufos Sorry, what makes that more general? `pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset is pandas.DateOffset`, so why bother using the longer path?

Comment: Looks like I got confused by the previous version of the answer which included `MonthOffset`

Answer (score 11):

Suppose you have a dataframe of the following format, where you have to add integer months to a date column.

| Start_Date | Months_to_add |
| --- | --- |
| 2014-06-01 | 23 |
| 2014-06-01 | 4 |
| 2000-10-01 | 10 |
| 2016-07-01 | 3 |
| 2017-12-01 | 90 |
| 2019-01-01 | 2 |

In such a scenario, using [Zero's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46741436/10395275) or [mattblack's code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46741423/10395275) won't be useful. You have to use lambda function over the rows where the function takes 2 arguments -

1. A date to which months need to be added to
2. A month value in integer format

You can use the following function:

```
# Importing required modules
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# Defining the function
def add_months(start_date, delta_period):
  end_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=delta_period)
  return end_date
```

After this you can use the following code snippet to add months to the `Start_Date` column. Use `progress_apply` functionality of [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Refer to this Stackoverflow answer on `progress_apply` : [Progress indicator during pandas operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34365537/10395275).

```
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

df["End_Date"] = df.progress_apply(lambda row: add_months(row["Start_Date"], row["Months_to_add"]), axis = 1)
```

Here's the full code form dataset creation, for your reference:

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

# Initilize a new dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Add Start Date column
df["Start_Date"] = ['2014-06-01T00:00:00.000000000',
                    '2014-06-01T00:00:00.000000000',
                    '2000-10-01T00:00:00.000000000',
                    '2016-07-01T00:00:00.000000000',
                    '2017-12-01T00:00:00.000000000',
                    '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000000000']

# To convert the date column to a datetime format
df["Start_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Start_Date"])
# Add months column
df["Months_to_add"] = [23, 4, 10, 3, 90, 2]

# Defining the Add Months function
def add_months(start_date, delta_period):
  end_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=delta_period)
  return end_date

# Apply function on the dataframe using lambda operation.
df["End_Date"] = df.progress_apply(lambda row: add_months(row["Start_Date"], row["Months_to_add"]), axis = 1)
```

You will have the final output dataframe as follows.

| Start_Date | Months_to_add | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-06-01 | 23 | 2016-05-01 |
| 2014-06-01 | 4 | 2014-10-01 |
| 2000-10-01 | 10 | 2001-08-01 |
| 2016-07-01 | 3 | 2016-10-01 |
| 2017-12-01 | 90 | 2025-06-01 |
| 2019-01-01 | 2 | 2019-03-01 |

Please add to comments if there are any issues with the above code.
All the best!

Answer (score 6):

I believe that the simplest and most efficient (faster) way to solve this is to transform the date to monthly periods with `to_period(M)`, add the result with the values of the **Months_to_add** column and then retrieve the data as datetime with the `.dt.to_timestamp()` command.

Using the sample data created by @Aruparna Maity

| Start_Date | Months_to_add |
| --- | --- |
| 2014-06-01 | 23 |
| 2014-06-20 | 4 |
| 2000-10-01 | 10 |
| 2016-07-05 | 3 |
| 2017-12-15 | 90 |
| 2019-01-01 | 2 |

```
df['End_Date'] = ((df['Start_Date'].dt.to_period('M')) + df['Months_to_add']).dt.to_timestamp()
df.head(6)
#output
    Start_Date  Months_to_add   End_Date
0   2014-06-01  23              2016-05-01
1   2014-06-20  4               2014-10-01
2   2000-10-01  10              2001-08-01
3   2016-07-05  3               2016-10-01
4   2017-12-15  90              2025-06-01
5   2019-01-01  2               2019-03-01
```

If the exact day is needed, just repeat the process, but changing the periods to days

```
df['End_Date'] = ((df['End_Date'].dt.to_period('D')) + df['Start_Date'].dt.day -1).dt.to_timestamp()
#output:
    Start_Date  Months_to_add   End_Date
0   2014-06-01  23              2016-05-01
1   2014-06-20  4               2014-10-20
2   2000-10-01  10              2001-08-01
3   2016-07-05  3               2016-10-05
4   2017-12-15  90              2025-06-15
5   2019-01-01  2               2019-03-01
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way using numpy [timedelta64](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.timedelta64)

```
df['date'] + np.timedelta64(plus_month_period, 'M')
0   2017-01-10 07:27:18
1   2017-01-31 07:27:18
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Why is the result a little short of what it should be? Is there any significance to `07:27:18`?