# pandas - add 1 month to a pd.Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, timedelta

I have multiple df, and they are indexed with timestamps for consecutive months. For example:

```
1996-01-01 01:00:00
1996-02-01 01:00:00
1996-03-01 01:00:00
1996-04-01 01:00:00
1996-05-01 01:00:00
1996-06-01 01:00:00
```

I'm trying to create a function where I can add an arbitrary number of rows onto the df, continuing on from whatever the last month happens to be.  I tried to solve this by using:

```
df.iloc[-1].name + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='M')
```

in a for loop, but this only seems to add 30 days, instead of changing the month value +1.  Is there a more reliable way to fetch a pd.Timestamp and add 1 month?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741423/add-months-to-a-date-in-pandas