# How to increment date column by month in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that has a column named "date_col". 
date_col has 1000+ dates, and the dates are only: 01/01/2011 and 01/01/2012.

This is what I tried:

```
table['date_col'] = pd.date_range(start='3/1/2011', 
                                  periods=len(table['date_col']), freq='d')
```

How can I easily change the months to be something else than just 01/01?

Comment: Could you please add some code that you have written and tried?

Comment: table['date_col'] = pd.date_range(start = '3/1/2011', periods=len(table['date_col']), freq='d')

Comment: I do not want to change anything else in the table. That code will change the year too. I only want to change the month and days.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add months to a date in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741423/add-months-to-a-date-in-pandas)

Comment: What would you like i.e. `01/01` changed into?

Comment: anything but 01/01

Comment: yes r.ook that answered the question with a little tweak. Here is the code:

table['date_col'] = table['date_col'] + pd.DateOffset(months = 2)

Comment: oh, it still just change the dates to the same dates. It is not randomly incrementing it tho! so the date would be 3/1/2011 and 3/1/2012. It would be nice to have different months and days randomly in each column.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the date column into a `datetime` object so you can manipulate it easily, something like this should work:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_str = '01/01/2012'
date_format = '%d/%m/%Y'
date = datetime.strptime(date_str, date_format)

# just change the day
date = date.replace(day=2)
```

Comment: I have already tried that by incrementing it with weeks, but it will also change the year. I do not want to change the year. I only need to change the months and day. The years should be the same. I need to keep the year as is and change the months and days.

date_str = '2012/01/01'
date_format = '%Y/%m/%d'
date = datetime.strptime(date_str, date_format)
next_day = timedelta(weeks=1) + date
table['date_col']  = next_day.strftime(date_format)

Comment: If you only want to change the day without changing the year or the month now it should work.