# How to add 1 more month to datetime that end up as the first day of month?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

My expectation:

`'2019-02-01' + 1 month`
`-> '2019-03-01'`

My try code:

> `(pd.Timedelta(1, unit = 'M') + pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01'))`

However it ends up with this result:

`Timestamp('2019-03-03 10:29:06')`

I want it to be exactly the first day of the month

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741423/add-months-to-a-date-in-pandas

Comment: Use `pd.to_datetime('2019-02-01') + pd.DateOffset(months=1)`