# Add "number of months" column to a column that contains datetime objects

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have the following table:

| date | months to add |
| --- | --- |
| 02-2022 | 2 |
| 05-2012 | 1 |

where the "date" column contains datetime objects, while "months to add" contains integers.
I want to obtain the following series of datetime objects:

| new date |
| --- |
| 04-2022 |
| 06-2012 |

EDIT:
It turns out this question had already been partially answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67530305/13410195).
I simply replaced the call to `progress_apply` (which now throws "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'progress_apply') with a simple `apply`.

Comment: For your purposes, what is "31-Jan-2022 + 1 month"?  Is it truncated to the last day of the following month?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formatting. I actually don't need the granularity of the day, so I edited my question

Comment: Almost! When I first searched for a solution I saw this answer but I didn't see the non-accepted solution. It is almost the correct answer because it uses the method progress_apply which with my version of Pandas throws "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'progress_apply'". I simply replaced with a normal "apply" and it works like a charm.

Comment: What should I do in this case? flag the question as a duplicate? It is not exactly a duplicate because in the other question the answer that came in handy to me is not the accepted one.

Comment: @chattershuts, good question.  I'd edit the question to point explicitly to the non-accepted answer in the other question — so future searchers can benefit from your investigation — then close as a dup.

Comment: I don't think I have enough privileges to close it as a duplicate