# How do I view progress the conversion from list to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tqdm

is it possibel to see progress under code?

```
morpheme = [[('apple','Noun')]....]
word2_df= pd.DataFrame(sum(morpheme_test,[]), columns = ['word','type'])
```

It worked well when extracting 20 from the list and proceeding.

However, when I used the whole data, it took too long to get it to work, so I had to make sure it worked.

So, I refer to the following url, but I do not know if it applies to my case.

[Progress indicator during pandas operations (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603270/progress-indicator-during-pandas-operations-python)

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how to check the progress of the above code.

Comment: What's wrong with the answer that you linked?

Comment: frankly, In the answer, I did not understand how to actually apply it.

Comment: The biggest problem here is `sum`, which is O(N^2). Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` or similar instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097

Comment: You are right. It was very helpful. Thank you.