# Is it possible to use tqdm for pandas merge operation?

Tags: python, pandas, tqdm

I could find examples of tqdm progress bar being used for group by and other pandas operations. But couldn't find anything on merge or join.

Is it possible to use tqdm on pandas for merge ?

Comment: @johny Mudly I've already seen this question. There is no example of pandas merge/join operation in any of the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tqdm supports pandas and various operations within it. For merging two large dataframes and showing the progress, you could do it this way:

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lkey': 1000*['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],'lvalue': np.random.randint(0,int(1e8),4000)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'rkey': 1000*['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],'rvalue': np.random.randint(0, int(1e8),4000)})

#this is how you activate the pandas features in tqdm
tqdm.pandas()
#call the progress_apply feature with a dummy lambda 
df1.merge(df2, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey').progress_apply(lambda x: x)
```

More details are available on this thread:
[Progress indicator during pandas operations (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603270/progress-indicator-during-pandas-operations-python)

Comment: I think, it just shows the progress of the apply function, rather than the actual merge operation.

Comment: The only possible way which I found is described here (it's using Dask as a workaround): https://stackoverflow.com/a/68936833/3921758

Comment: To be clear, THIS DOES NOT WORK. As per the comment by @Kapil , this will merge the dfs and then run through all of the rows and do nothing, and show you how fast it is to run through all the rows and do nothing. It will not show you the progress of the merge.