# Use tqdm over a sequence of merge operations

Tags: python, pandas, merge, tqdm

I need a `tqdm` progress bar over a set of (possibly long) set of merge operations.
In my application, I have a set of operations in cascade like the following

```py
data = data.merge(get_data_source1(), on="id", how="left")\
           .merge(get_data_source2(), on="id", how="left")\
           ...
           .merge(get_data_sourceN(), on="id", how="left")
```

It is not relevant what the `get_data_source<i>` functions do, they pull the data from somewhere (for instance, from different files or different DBs) and they returns a DataFrame with an "id" column and that it takes a few seconds.

I would need a progress bar that goes with N. This is probably feasible encapsulating each merge operation within `lambda` functions and put them into an iterable, but it looks like an overengineered and hard to read solution if I try to think of it (please correct me if you think I'm wrong).
Also, I'm aware that is possible to add a progress bar to each merge operation using the `progress_apply` function (like reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341817/merging-two-large-dataframes-on-specific-column-with-progress-bar-showing)), but that would generate several (N) short progress bar rather than a single one.

For the sake of emulating a working setup, let's consider this toy example

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100,3)), columns=["id","A", "B"])

def get_data(col):
    time.sleep(1.0)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100,2)), columns=["id",col])

data.merge(get_data("C"), on="id", how="left")\
    .merge(get_data("D"), on="id", how="left")\
    .merge(get_data("E"), on="id", how="left")\
    .merge(get_data("F"), on="id", how="left")\
    .merge(get_data("G"), on="id", how="left")\
    .merge(get_data("H"), on="id", how="left")
```

What would the best way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

Here's a snippet on some sample data frames, but it would work with any data frame iterable, just wrap it with `tqdm`.

```
import functools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

N = 10
columns = [["A", "B"], ["C"], ["D", "E", "F"]]
dfs = [
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "key": range(N),
            **{c: np.random.rand(N) for c in cols}
        }
    )
    for cols in columns
]
functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x.merge(y), tqdm(dfs[1:]), dfs[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list with your values that you want to apply the function get_data to, and iterate over this list with tqdm.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import tqdm


data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100,3)), columns=["id","A", "B"])

def get_data(col):
    time.sleep(1.0)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100,2)), columns=["id",col])

values = ["C","D","E","F","G","H"]

for i in tqdm.tqdm(values):
    data = data.merge(get_data(i), on="id", how="left")
data
```

You can either assign the merged dataframe to the data dataframe at each step like in the above example, or use the inplace parameter to avoid returning a new dataframe at each step.

EDIT:
As all the get_data functions are different, I suggest as the question did to create an iterable with the functions. It is not required to use lambdas, as the example below shows:

```
functions = [get_data1,get_data2,get_data3]
for func in functions:
    data = func(param1,param2,param3)
```

This will iterate over all the functions of the list and execute them with the given parameters.

Comment: Actually each ```get_data``` function are different. They are supposed to pull the data from different sources (e.g., different DBs). Sorry, I simplified the task to much, I'll edit the question

Comment: Would it be possible to have only one function taking as argument the filename (or DB access) for exmaple? I mean, is the accessed source the only differing part for each functio ?

Comment: No is not. They are fetching from different source in different ways (e.g. with different queries and different post-filters)

Comment: I guess then the only solution I see is to ceate an iterable with the functions as you stated in your question. Note that you do not need lambdas. See the edit I made to the answer!