# Create a counter for each row processed in apply function

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I was wondering if it is possible to create a counter for each row as you apply a function to a Pandas dataframe like this:

```
data['column'] = data.apply(lambda x: function(x['url']), axis=1)
```

The output should be something similar to this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you think something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603270/progress-indicator-during-pandas-operations) ?

Comment: @jezrael I have tried it and works very well, thanks

Comment: So it is duplicate, in your opinion?

Comment: @jezrael I guess we can mark it as duplicate yes.