# Progress bar for pandas DataFrame multy operations with .agg()

Tags: python, pandas, tqdm

I want to apply .agg pandas operations to a huge dataset

As an example, I have this code:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 
                   "B":[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0], 
                   "C":[1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 10.0],
                   "D":[2.0, 5.0, 3.0, 6.0, 4.0, 2.0, 5.0, 1.0, 2.0],
                   "E":['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a']}) 

df2 = df.groupby('B').agg({
                           'C': 'mean',
                           'D': 'sum',
                           'E': lambda x: x.mode()
                         })
print(df2)
```

The problem is that my original dataset has 2.000.000 of rows. Transforming it to 130.000 takes some minutes and **I would like to see a progress bar**

I've tried with `tqdm` but I don't know how to apply it here. Is there any function similar to `.progress_apply()` but for `.agg()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603270/progress-indicator-during-pandas-operations

Comment: I saw that before, but I can't do nothing with it. I don't need to apply a simple operation with apply(). Instead I need to apply several operation with agg()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print the progress as you go, where progress is measured by the fraction of the groups for which statistics are computed. But I'm not sure how much the loop will slow down your computations.

```
agger = {
   'C': 'mean',
   'D': 'sum',
   'E': lambda x: x.mode()}


gcols = ['B'] # columns defining the groups
groupby = df.groupby(gcols)

ngroups = len(groupby)
gfrac = 0.3 # fraction of groups for which you want to print progress
gfrac_size = max((1, int(ngroups*gfrac)))
groups = []
rows = []
for i,g in enumerate(groupby):

    if (i+1)%gfrac_size == 0:
        print('{:.0f}% complete'.format(100*(i/ngroups)))

    gstats = g[1].agg(agger)
    if i==0:
        if gstats.ndim==2:
            newcols = gstats.columns.tolist()
        else:
            newcols = gstats.index.tolist()

    groups.append(g[0])
    rows.append(gstats.values.flat)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(rows), columns=newcols)
if len(gcols) == 1:
    df3.index = groups
else:
    df3.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(groups, names=gcols)
df3 = df3.astype(df[newcols].dtypes)
df3
       C     D  E
1.0  1.5  10.0  a
2.0  3.0  12.0  b
3.0  7.0   8.0  a
```

An alternative (though somewhat hacky) way would be to take advantage of the fact that you use your own function `lambda x: x.mode`. Since you're already compromising speed using this function, you can write a class that stores information about progress. For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 
                   "B":[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0], 
                   "C":[1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 10.0],
                   "D":[2.0, 5.0, 3.0, 6.0, 4.0, 2.0, 5.0, 1.0, 2.0],
                   "E":['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a']}) 

df2 = df.groupby('B').agg({
                           'C': 'mean',
                           'D': 'sum',
                           'E': lambda x: x.mode()
                         })
print(df2)

class ModeHack:

    def __init__(self, size=5, N=10):
        self.ix = 0
        self.K = 1 
        self.size = size
        self.N = N

    def mode(self, x):
        self.ix = self.ix + x.shape[0]
        if self.K*self.size <= self.ix:
            print('{:.0f}% complete'.format(100*self.ix/self.N))
            self.K += 1

        return x.mode()

    def reset(self):    
        self.ix = 0
        self.K = 1

mymode = ModeHack(size=int(.1*df.shape[0]), N=df.shape[0])
mymode.reset()

agger = {
   'C': 'mean',
   'D': 'sum',
   'E': lambda x: mymode.mode(x)}

df3 = df.groupby('B').agg(agger)
```

Comment: for the example it works very good hehehehe, but how can I apply the same in a dataframe filtered with two columns instead of one? `df.B.nunique` is only valid for one column...

Comment: I just modified it so that you get the number of groups from the groupby object. So if you change to df.groupby(['A','B']) for instance, it would give you 9 in your example.

Comment: modified again to allow for multiple columns in the groupby statement

Comment: It is a very nice attempt, but it extend the time computing a lot. I guess it is not possible to do it in an efficient way. I improved your code with the use of `tqdm` pack. It has a more friendly display. Thank you very much for your time.