# "Refreshing" Command Line in Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I started learning python few days ago, I wrote an easy program. A user enters data and it gives information about the data.

```
while True:
 x = input("Enter Data: ")
        
 if x == z:
            print("")
          
           
 if x == y:
            print("") 
 if x == l:
            print("")
          
           
 if x == k:
            print("")
```

I am using program in windows command line. What I am trying to do is: when you "enter data" and program gives you information, you press enter and command line refresh and "enter data" appears again.

Comment: Oh, do you mean that it is constantly asking you to enter data? and you don't want it to?

Comment: there is no problem with program, it is working(this is not a full code of program). I want command line to "refresh"(dunno if it's write term"). When i start program it says: Enter Data, i enter it, it gives me information. then it repeats "Enter Data", but under information it gave to me. i want it to delete everything and ask on the blank page to "Enter Data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you can use `cls` to clear screen (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-python-interpreter-console) for details):

```
import os
import sys

while True:
    value = raw_input('Enter data: ')

    if value == 'quit':
        break

    print value

    # wait for enter key
    sys.stdin.read(1)
    os.system('cls')
```

[Curses](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses) example:

```
import curses

w = curses.initscr()

while True:
    w.addstr("Enter data: ")
    value = w.getstr()

    if value == 'quit':
        break

    w.addstr('data: %s\n' % value)

    w.addstr('Press any key to continue')
    w.getch()
    w.clear()
    w.refresh()

curses.endwin()
```

Answer (score 0):

`while True:` means "keep doing this".  So it's going to keep asking you to enter data.  Maybe what you're looking for is to [define a function](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/functions.html) instead: `def ask():` instead, and then in the command line, type `ask()`, and it will prompt you only the one time, which is what I am guessing you want.