# Python 2.7 - Completely clear Console, including the input line?

Tags: python, console

I've tried the solution here - [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-python-interpreter-console) - to clear the Console, and it works, but it still leaves the C:/Python27> line. Is there any way of clearing everything, including this? I'm new to Python, I'm trying to make a simple Noughts and Crosses game, for which I want a clear Console. I usually use VB.NET, where there are no input lines and this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If this was me, I would see if I could perhaps control the size of the window being used, such that I know the exact number of lines on screen, and then print an exact number of blank lines such that the command prompt is not longer shown.

After this point, your noughts and crosses game I assume will print to screen multiple times, where each 'time' is going to be a new 'frame' of your game.

Comment: +1 for a perfectly valid answer, though I'm concerned - do you think this is the only way of doing this? I'd like to do it the same way I would using VB.NET, with a clear screen, so I can print things such as an array for Noughts and Crosses, and then change the cursor position to overwrite them, rather than reprint the whole thing every time. Have I picked the wrong language here, do you reckon?

Comment: It's difficult to tell which way is best. Are you planning on interacting with the command line using the mouse pointer?
If so, it might be easier to use something like wxPython to create a GUI with an array of buttons that act upon your noughts and crosses array in the background (although this obviously comes with the overhead of learning how to use a potentially new module).

Comment: Sorry, I miscommunicated. When I said the cursor, I meant the blinking underscore on the Console. So in VB.NET Console I would move that around the screen and then write characters over characters I've already written to update information without having to print a whole screen every time. Is Python the wrong tool for that sort of thing?

Comment: Perhaps, though I don't have any experience of interacting with the console in this way using python (though I have done so with .NET before, so understand what you wish to achieve).