# Completely clearing the terminal window using Python

Tags: python, unix, terminal, os.system

How can I in Python (v 2.7.2) completely clear the terminal window?

This doesn't work since it just adds a bunch of new lines and the user can still scroll up and see earlier commands

```
import os
os.system('clear')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear python interpreter console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-python-interpreter-console)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26979/47066) that the correct command to use was `tput reset`

```
import os

clear = lambda : os.system('tput reset')
clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this and it works:

```
>>> import os
>>> clear = lambda : os.system('clear')
>>> clear()
```

### BEFORE

[image: Before]

### AFTER `clear()`

[image: After]

Comment: This gives me `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`, using Python 2.7.2

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it should have been a `lambda`.

Comment: It doesn't clear everything that has been printed by Python before the command is executed

Comment: @OskarPersson It just leaves a `0` in the end. Could you give us a screen shot of your attempts?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

On Linux:

```
import os
os.system('clear')
```

Comment: That works on Windows but not linux. In the end, its all about how the client terminal program honors the control message. On my linux machine, the screen will clear but my terminal emulator will not clear its history.

Answer (score 0):

for windows:

```
import os
def clear(): os.system('cls')
```

for linux:

```
import os
def clear(): os.system('clear')
```

then to clear the terminal simply call:

```
clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of importing any libraries.
Simply call the cls function.

```
cls()
```

Comment: That doesn't work. `NameError: name 'cls' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

I am using Linux and I found it much easier to just use

```
import os
```

in the header of the code and

```
os.system('clear')
```

in the middle of my script. No lambda or whatever was needed to get it done. 
What I guess is important to pay attention to, is to have the `import os` in the header of the code, the very beginning where all other `import` commands are being written...

Answer (score 0):

Adding for completeness, if you want to do this without launching an external command, do:

```
print('\x1bc')
```

Only tested on Linux.

Answer (score -1):

You can not control the users terminal. That's just how it works.

Think of it like write only.