# Clearing previous terminal output in python

Tags: python

Is there any way to clear the terminal's previous output? If so, how? Here is a code example to work off of.

```
print "Hello..."
#Code that clears previous terminal output
print "All cleared!"
```

I know that there is an iOS module for the mobile app pythonista that can do this, but I am wondering how to do it on Linux.

Comment: @TheNotGoodAtCodeGuy what's the point? The answer is already given here [How to clear python interpreter console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-python-interpreter-console)

Comment: @TheNotGoodAtCodeGuy why can't you just click on the link and read the answer there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you are on Windows or Linux, you can do:

```
import os
os.system('cls')   #Windows
os.system('clear') #Linux
```

Example:

```
print 'Hello...'
os.system('clear') #or os.system('cls') for Windows
print "All cleared!"
```