# How to clear a Rebol console?

Tags: console, call, rebol

Is there any way to clear a Rebol console? (Maybe there are too many things in the console and I don't want to open a new one ;-) or I need to print some things in a clear console).

I know we can call `cls` in Windows or `clear` in Linux to clear the console. But how can I do it in Rebol, just in console or some script files?

In Rebol, I know we can do a system call with something like `call "cmd"`. But `call "cls"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This works also with

```
print "^L"
```

[and there is a complete terminal control dialect available](http://web.archive.org/web/20130121141033/http://www.rebolforces.com/articles/tui-dialect.html)

Comment: This is one of the features just rudimentary in Rebol3 compared to Rebol(2)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer that works with Rebol 2. I haven't taken the plunge to R3 yet.

print "^(1B)[J"

This reference to rebol console commands might be helpful.

http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-18.html

Answer (score 1):

In my systems simply hit Ctrl-L. But may depends on terminal....

Comment: Quick answer! Thx! The idea occurs to me when I want to write a script in which clearing console will be better. I searched and found a python solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-python-interpreter-console , and I think Rebol should be able do this too. :-)