# Need Solution for incorrect guess loop

Tags: python

Ok, I am creating a memory game. I have developed where the programme asks the user what word was removed, and have successfully developed the part that moves on if they get it right. However, I am struggling to find how to get it to only fail the user if they get it wrong three times. Here's what I have so far:

```
def q1():
    qone + 1
    print("\n"*2)
    while qone <= 3:
        question1 = input("Which word has been removed? ")
        if question1 == removed:
            print("\n"*1)
            print("Correct")
            print("\n"*2)
            q2()
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
            q1()
    else:
        print("You're all out of guesses!")
        input("Press enter to return to the menu")
        menu()
    return
`
```

Comment: Why is the function calling itself?

Comment: what do you think `qone + 1` accomplishes; *hint whatever your answer is it doesn't*

Comment: wow that's a bit rude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is to remove recursion and simply increase the counter of failed tries.

```
def q1():
    qone = 0
    print("\n"*2)
    while qone < 3:
        question1 = input("Which word has been removed? ")
        if question1 == removed:
            print("\n"*1)
            print("Correct")
            print("\n"*2)
            q2()
            return
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
            qone += 1

    print("You're all out of guesses!")
    input("Press enter to return to the menu")
    menu()
    return
```

Comment: I assumed variable "removed" is a global variable.

Comment: They are allowed three guesses

Comment: @Pynchia I changed <= to <. Thank you.

Comment: @adamrjac I don't have the rest of your code - you need to test it yourself and report back if you need more help :)

Comment: yeah, I'm guessing the else wasn't necessary?

Comment: Indeed, recursion was kinda counterintuitive here - it's way easier to simply loop it three times.

Comment: I suppose I should also ask, is there a simple clear screen command, I am currently just printing 1000 lines. My teacher says this is fine, should I just keep it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-python-interpreter-console

Answer (score 0):

1. When you do `qone + 1`, you need to assign it to something (so perhaps `qone += 1`)
2. What is the else outside the while loop linked to?
3. You seem to have a recursive definition going. Think carefully about the chain of calls that would be made and what your base case should be. Once you know these things, it would be easier for you to write the code. Also, think about whether you need recursion at all: in this case, it doesn't seem like you would.

Comment: The OP should not be using recursion at all

Comment: I agree. Looks to me as though there is some muddling of concepts going on.

Comment: I am very confused, qone has already been assigned. Do you want full code?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this and python

Comment: Updating your question with all the relevant code won't hurt. Also, if you are sure you need recursion, explaining why you think so would also clear things up

Comment: `range` gives you a specific sequence of numbers. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range)

Comment: Removed was a global variable, so it had already been assigned, dw programme all fixed now

Comment: @adamrjac You should accept the answer that helped you if your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

You should not have the function calling itself, use range for the  loop, if the user gets the question correct go to the next question, if they get it wrong print the output:

```
def q1(removed):
    print("\n"*2)
    for i in range(3):
        question1 = input("Which word has been removed? ")
        if question1 == removed:
            print("\nCorrect")
            return q2()
        print("\n\nIncorrect")
    input("You're all out of guesses!\nPress enter to return to the menu")
    return menu()
```

If the user has three bad guesses the loop will end and you will hit the `"You're all out of guesses!\nPress enter to return to the menu"`