# Python program to take user input and refresh console without "scrolling"

Tags: python

Let's say I have this little Python program:

```
def drawLine():

    userInput = input("Coordinates:")
    userInput = userInput.split() # x y

    # Draw
    # ... some drawing algo which will print an "X" on the screen with x,y

drawLine()
drawLine()
```

Now notice that `drawLine()` is called twice, so that two inputs can be taken and two `X-es` be drawn. Unfortunately, console will scroll up. I want my python program "**to listen**" to user key presses and "**not scroll away**". Think of a mini-console Photoshop, which also does not scroll your canvas out of sight.

**Update**:
Problem is small enough to not employ a library.

Comment: If you don't want to use a library you will be writing a lot of fiddly code.  Use a library.

Comment: At the very least, check out the code the libraries use to get an idea of how it's done.

Comment: Checking libraries is a great idea. I figure this problem was already solved somewhere else. Mabye somebody knows without me spending couple of minutes or even hours with Google.

Comment: Then remove the *Ideally* from your update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VT100 control codes:

```
input("something:")
print( '\x1b[1A\x1b[2K\x1b[1A')
input("something else:")
```

There must be something similar for windows.

Comment: Thanks @xvan, these work great for my purposes - http://www.ccs.neu.edu/research/gpc/MSim/vona/terminal/VT100_Escape_Codes.html

Answer (score 1):

Probably `Curses` library is what you need in this case.

It allows you to display string at given coordinates: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/curses.html#curses.window.addstr

You can also leave echo mode so you can handle keyboard input as you want without printing it to console: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/curses.html#curses.noecho.

Comment: No Libraries! Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question but I think it can be achieve by clearing console and redrawing the 'frame'.  [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-python-interpreter-console)

Answer (score 1):

If it was alright to keep the input below the console, you could use a class to keep your canvas in an array and just render it when you need to.

Here is an example:

```
#X-Drawer
class Canvas:
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.c = []
        for i in range(w * h):
            self.c.append(' ')
        print len(self.c)
    def render(self):
        u = 0
        s = ""
        for i in range(len(self.c)):
            s += self.c[i]
            if not i % self.w:
                s += "\n"
        print s
    def drawX(self, x, y):
        n = [(x, y), (x + 1, y + 1), (x + 2, y + 2), (x + 2, y), (x, y + 2)]
        for i in n:
            v = i[0] * self.w + i[1]
            if v < len(self.c):
                self.c[v] = 'X'
    def drawLine(self, x, d):
        n = []
        if d:
            n = [(x, y), (x + 1, y + 1), (x + 2, y + 2)]
        else:
            n = [(x, y), (x + 1, y + 1), (x + 2, y + 2)]
        for i in n:
            v = i[0] * self.w + i[1]
            if v < len(self.c):
                self.c[v] = 'X'

def clearScreen():
    for i in range(64):
        print

c = Canvas(25, 25)

while True:
    clearScreen()
    c.render()
    i = raw_input("Coordinates: ").split()
    c.drawX(int(i[0]), int(i[1]))
```

You could also replace the clearScreen with an os call to `clr` ( [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-python-interpreter-console) ) instead of printing 64 lines.

Note: My example uses the drawX function, you could use the drawLine function and different coordinates to draw the lines.