# Facing Issue on Clearing Python Interpreter

Tags: python

Using Python 2.7.10 on Windows Machine I tried all of following to clear the `interpreter`

```
import os
os.system('cls')
clear()
cls()
cls
clear
```

but I am not able to clear the interpreter by code while the `Clear All` option is already in R-click. Can you please let me know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console

Comment: What IDE is that?  Any such capability is going to be a feature of the IDE's text display, not anything built into Python.  There's no guarantee that the feature is accessible from Python at all.

Comment: That doesn't look like the default python interpreter. It's likely one in an IDE in which case the os.system() call probably won't work. Re-word your question with the IDE you are using and maybe someone on here can help you.