# Clearing the text from the python shell

Tags: python

OK, so I am currently messing around coding hangman in python and was wondering if I can clear what it says in the python shell as I don't just wan't the person to read the word.

```
import time
keyword = input(" Please enter the word you want the person to guess")
lives = int(input("How many lives would you like to have?"))
print ("There are ", len(keyword), "letters in the word")

time.sleep(2)

guess = input("please enter your guess")
```

I would like to remove all the text  in the shell.

Comment: show us the code.....why is the word visible at the beginning?

Comment: Are you asking about [clearing the entire shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console) or clearing just specific text displayed? As @depperm mentioned, please share some code or otherwise be more clear/specific about what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

if you are a windows user use this:

```
import os
os.system("cls")
```

Mac/linux then :

```
import os
os.system("clear")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import subprocess
import time

tmp=subprocess.call('clear', shell=True) # 'cls' in windows
keyword = input(" Please enter the word you want the person to guess")
lives = int(input("How many lives would you like to have?"))
print ("There are ", len(keyword), "letters in the word")

time.sleep(2)
```

Save the code in a python file. Then execute it from shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("\n" * 100)
```

There is no other way to do it then to just spam the console.

Answer (score 0):

`os.system("cls")` for windows or `os.system("clear")` for mac/linux.

Then put that line of code where you wish for the program to delete all the text in the shell.