# Python - Rewrite a 2D list / numpy array in the Console

Tags: list, numpy, console

I want to rewrite/replace a 2d list or numpy array (whatever is easier) in the console:
   e.g.:

```
[[_,_,_],
 [_,_,_],
 [x,_,_]]
```

will be replaced with

```
[[_,_,_],
 [x,_,_],
 [_,_,_]]
```

which will be replaced with

```
[[x,_,_],
 [_,_,_],
 [_,_,_]]
```

and so on...so it looks like the x is moving across the "board".
I already wrote the function that enables me to print the lists one after the other but i would rather replace them in the console output.

thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import time
import numpy as np

def cls():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')

x0 = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0],
               [1, 0, 0]])

x1 = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
               [2, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0]])

x2 = np.array([[3, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0]])

print(x0)
time.sleep(1)
cls()
print(x1)
time.sleep(1)
cls()
print(x2)
```

see [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console)

Comment: unfortunately it's not working for me.
I still get the individual arrays but with a small arrow pointing upwards at the start of the array.

is it maybe because i use pycharm?

Comment: Which operating system? I tried using Spyder, don't have PyCharm to test. Could you try IDLE or your system command prompt?