# How to clear shell in Python in IDLE? CTRL+L, os.system('cls') and sp.call('cls',shell=True) does not work

Tags: python-3.x

I am new on Python and I want to clear the shell. I've tried CTRL+L, os.system('cls') and sp.call('cls',shell=True) but that only outputs 0.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console

Answer (score 0):

(CTRL+L will not work if you are using Windows. Sorry.)

MORE: sp.call('cls',shell=True) only works on OS X in shell.

EVEN MORE: os.system('cls') (for windows only), works for Terminal window(CMD)
presuming you are using OS X:
Here's a solution I found:

```py
import subprocess as sp
tmp = sp.call('cls',shell=True)
```

Hope this helps,
The snake 727.

Comment: @WuffleTuffle If this is not the right answer, leave a comment to explain why. Thanks!