# Code to clear console and variables in Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

Tried many suggestions to **clear console and variables** in Spyder using code not CTRL+L but they do not work.

wondering any effective suggestion what the code can be used for clearing Spyder console and variables.

using `get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')` will make the variable explorer not updated.

Comment: CTRL + L does clear the terminal screen but it does not clear variables--you need a kernel restart for that. What do you mean?

Answer (score 13):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This code both clears the console and removes all variables present on the namespace at the same time:

```
try:
    from IPython import get_ipython
    get_ipython().magic('clear')
    get_ipython().magic('reset -f')
except:
    pass
```

It also has the advantage that it works inside and outside Spyder.

*Note*: Right now this approach generates [an error](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-kernels/issues/91) in the console after it's run. We'll fix that error in the next Spyder version (**3.3.4**), to be released in March/2019.

Comment: It works. Thanks!
But somewhat different with MATLAB, although variables in variable explorer are cleared, they are still shown there but not disappear. There is an option of removing all variables on the top left of the variable explorer, it can clear all variable and make them disappear.

Comment: Ok, that's the only way I know to do what you want. If you find my answer helpful, please mark it as so by selecting the green check mark on the left.

Comment: Another issue caused by the code is the variable explorer is disconnected with the code, that is variables cannot be updated. Even running the code file including the code above, there is no variable shown in the variable explorer.

Comment: @Gamp, you're totally right. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Hi this one clears functions also, how can we just clears varibales in "variable explorer"

Comment: Right now we don't make a difference between variables and functions, sorry.

Comment: This code now returns a warning `DeprecationWarning: magic(...) is deprecated since IPython 0.13 (warning added in 8.1), use run_line_magic(magic_name, parameter_s).`.

Comment: @AustinDowney, we don't support IPython 8 yet. When we add support for it, we'll fix that warning.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way that I have come across to clear the Spyder console programmatically is:

```
print("\033[H\033[J")
```

From [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console) and suggested by [Denis Rasulev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4440387/denis-rasulev) .

```
print("\014")
```

Also works.

Answer (score 1):

`cls` and `clear-host` work in (!) the Console.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system('cls');
```

This works for me :)

Comment: `sh: cls: command not found`

Not working for me and `'clear'` worked instead.

Answer (score -2):

seen it elsewhere here, not my code, but:

```py
import os
os.system('clear')
```

Comment: Can you share the link where you saw it? More context always helps.