# How to restart kernel in python through code in spyder to avoid repetitively and manually doing it?

Tags: python, spyder, ensemble-learning

I am ensemble 2 models in syder. ( A RNN and an encoder-decoder both running on same data set). Each of them has 100 models saved in .h5 format. After loading and running RNN if I try to load models for Encoder-Decoder the system becomes slow. The solution that I found was to restart the kernel by pressing ctrl+.  . How do I automate it through code so that both the models can be run in single script?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no code to restart the kernel but the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54947631/438386) should be enough for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os._exit(00)
```

also works in jupyter notebooks