# Automatically cleaning the plot pane in Python Spyder

Tags: python, plot, anaconda, spyder

I would like to delete all the plots in the plot pane with some code so I can automatically "clear" the interface. I am aware there is a button you can click that deletes them all. However, I would like to avoid having to click manually on the plot pane to delete all the plots generated in the previous runs.

Right now I am already clearing the console and the variable explorer by using (which I got from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54943710/code-to-clear-console-and-variables-in-spyder)):

```
    try:
    from IPython import get_ipython
    get_ipython().magic('clear')
    get_ipython().magic('reset -f')
except:
    pass
```

Now I would like to add there something that also clears the plot pane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) It is not possible to remove all plots from the Plots pane using code, sorry.

Comment: Can this be a spyder setting ?