# How to clear the iPython console in Spyder?

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

How can the iPython console in Spyder be cleared with code in the console? I'm looking for something I could use in a simple text game.

This method doesn't work:

```
import os
clear = lambda: os.system("cls")
clear()
```

This command does clear the console,

```
print("\033[H\033[J", end="")
```

but it causes issues with other statements in the same console input. For instance,

```
print("\033[H\033[J", end="")
print("Hello world!")
```

**doesn't** print Hello world.

Comment: Your code works fine using `ipython` on windows, it clears the console and prints "Hello world". In the Cosnole in spyder the command clear() also works out of the box, so I see no problem there? What is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Spyder console, note that the Spyder console is an implementation of iPython. To clear the displayed text try:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().magic('clear')
```

There is additional information available on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54943710/code-to-clear-console-and-variables-in-spyder).

For your text game, you should only rely on this approach if the end product is going to be used in an iPython console (like the Spyder console).