# What does printf("\033[H\033[J") do in C?

Tags: c, ansi-escape

I have gone through the below strange sequence of characters in some random website. When compiled and executed, this sequence cleared all previous content in terminal.

Does this clear the `stdout` buffer or only the `tty` buffers?

```
int main()
{
    printf("\033[H\033[J");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's a terminal feature and has nothing to do with C

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

`\033` stands for `ESC` (ANSI value 27).

ESC [ is a kind of [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Sequence_elements) called [Control Sequence Introducer (CSI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences).

CSI commands starts with `ESC[` followed by zero or more parameters.

`\033[H` (ie, `ESC[H`) and `\033[J` are CSI codes.

`\033[H` moves the cursor to the top left corner of the screen (ie, the first column of the first row in the screen).

and

`\033[J` clears the part of the screen from the cursor to the end of the screen.

When used in combination, it results in the screen getting cleared with cursor positioned at the beginning of the screen.

This is the functionality that you get when using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or `clear` command on bash.

These CSI can have parameters as well. If none are provided, it will use the default values.

Answer (score 6):

If I am not mistaken, it makes use of [ANSI/VT100 Terminal Control Escape Sequences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm).

`\033` - ASCII escape character

`[H` - move the cursor to the home position

`[J` - erases the screen from the current line down to the bottom of the screen

However, this command may not be compatible in every terminal/console.

Comment: But it gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u7lj.png) to me .

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad You're using some kind of broken terminal that doesn't support control sequences at all. What IDE is this?

Comment: I am using codeblocks - it beeps bro..

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad It won't work in Codeblocks it seems. I had tried it earlier as well. But it does on most linux systems.

Comment: **sad nibba hours**

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Windows 10 console supports ANSI escape codes but **it's disabled by default**. You need to enable ANSI sequence support by creating a DWORD named `VirtualTerminalLevel` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` and set its value to 1 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences or better move to [Windows terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal). [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16755142/995714), [Windows console with ANSI colors handling](https://superuser.com/q/413073/241386)

Comment: link that works for  ANSI/VT100 Terminal Control Escape Sequences. is https://www2.ccs.neu.edu/research/gpc/VonaUtils/vona/terminal/vtansi.htm